# boolean operations with integers

Tags: integer, boolean, algebra, operations

This is probably pretty basic... but I don't seem to get it:

How does

```
(2 & 1) = 0
(3 & 1) = 1
(4 & 1) = 0
```

etc..

This pattern above seems to help find even numbers

or

```
(0 | 1) = 1
(1 | 1) = 1
(2 | 1) = 3
(3 | 1) = 4
(4 | 1) = 5
(5 | 1) = 5
```

I know how boolean algebra works between bits. But I don't understand how Boolean algebra works with integers (in C# at the least).

thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who cleared it up. Didn't realize it was that simple. The thought did cross my mind but I didn't do a mental conversion of the integers and operate on it bitwise.

Thanks!

Comment: This is all covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276706/what-are-bitwise-operators, although I understand why your search didn't find it - it uses 'bitwise', not 'boolean'.

Answer (score 6):

It works the same way in C# as it does in binary.

`2 | 1 = 3` and `4 | 1 = 5`.

To understand this, you need to think about the binary representation of 1,2,3,4,and 5:

`010 | 001 = 011` and `100 | 001 = 101`.

Similarly:

`010 & 001 = 000` and `011 & 001 = 001`

Answer (score 4):

You are getting the first result because you are performing a boolean `and` between the bit strings of the two numbers:

```
2 & 1 => 010 & 001 = 000 = 0
3 & 1 => 011 & 001 = 001 = 1
4 & 1 => 100 & 001 = 000 = 0
5 & 1 => 101 & 001 = 001 = 1
```

In effect, you are testing whether the '1' bit is set, which will only be true for odd numbers.

When performing `or` operations:

```
0 | 1 => 000 | 001 = 001 = 1
1 | 1 => 001 | 001 = 001 = 1
2 | 1 => 010 | 001 = 011 = 3
3 | 1 => 011 | 001 = 011 = 3
4 | 1 => 100 | 001 = 101 = 5
5 | 1 => 101 | 001 = 101 = 5
```

Since in this case the effect or the `or` is to always set the `1` bit, even numbers will be incremented by one to their nearest greater odd number.

Answer (score 1):

It is doing bitwise operations on the integer.  That it is doing a logical or/and of each bit in the first integer with the corresponding bit in the other integer.  It then returns the result of all of these operations.  For example, 4 = 0100 and 1 = 0001, a logical and of these would and bit the bits in order and get 0000 (since 0&0 = 0, 1&0 = 0, 0&0 = 0, and 0&1 = 0).  For or, you would get 0101 (since 0|0 = 0, 1|0 = 1, 0|0 = 0, and 0|1 = 1).  The trick is that these are bitwise operations, not logical operations which operate only on boolean values in C#.

Answer (score 1):

The key is that the CPU is doing 32 boolean operations in parallel, one for each bit position of the input integers (assuming 32 bit integers, of course).