# Performance of bitwise operators in javascript

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

One of the main ideas behind using bitwise operators in languages like C++/java/C# is that they're extremely fast. But I've heard that in javascript they're very slow (admittedly a few milliseconds probably doesn't matter much today). Why is this so?

([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654057/where-would-i-use-a-bitwise-operator-in-javascript) discusses when bitwise operators are used, so I'm changing the focus of this question to performance.)

Comment: bitwise operations, by this point in modern compiler development, are not "extremely fast," if you mean that i<<1 is faster than i*2 by any margin.

Comment: @Jimmy: it is irrelevant how advanced modern compilers are, compilers 30 years ago were smart enough to know that i<<1 is a little faster than i*2... you mean something more like "by this point in modern CPU speeds", because the nanosecond of difference on today's CPUs is pretty much negligible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When would you want to use them?  You would want to use them when you want to do bitwise operations.  Just like you'd use boolean operators to do boolean operations, and mathematical operators to do mathematical operations.

If you are comfortable with bitwise operators it is very natural to use them for some applications.  They can be used for many purposes other than an over-optimized boolean array.  Of course, these circumstances don't come up very often in Javascript programming, but that's no reason why the operators shouldn't be available.

Answer (score 20):

This is quite an old question, but no one seemed to answer the updated version.

The performance hit that you get with JavaScript that doesn't exist in C/C++ is the cast from [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) representation (how JavaScript strores all of its numbers) to a 32 bit integer to perform the bit manipulation and back.

Comment: This isn't really true anymore, considering that most JS JITs are perfectly fine with keeping a number just an int if nothing is done to it that warrants floating-point operations. While the specification mandates conversions, that's not how actual implementations have to work as long as the end result is the same.

Comment: Valid point, however this still applies to the question as asked.

Answer (score 16):

Nobody uses hex anymore?

```
function hextoRgb(c) {
    c = '0x' + c.substring(1);
    return [(c >> 16) & 255, (c >> 8) & 255, c & 255]; 
}

var c1 = hextoRgb('#191970');
alert('rgb(' + c1.join(',') + ')');
```

Comment: Actually shifting strings looks a bit weird to me. But on the other hand it's easier to read than `return /#([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})/i.exec(c).slice(1).map(function(e) {return parseInt(e, 16);});` for example.

Comment: @Robert - it may look weird but it would be much faster than the function you suggested since you have a regular expressions, loops, and closures

Answer (score 10):

I use bitwise shift of zero in JS to perform quick integer truncation:

```
var i=3.141532;
var iTrunc=i>>0; //3
```

Comment: That's a truly abhorrent use of the bit shift operator.

Comment: Yes, it's filthy, I know, but actually, it had its place in games programming for Flash. In AVM1 days this was the fastest way. Don't know if that holds for JS though.

Comment: var iTrunc = i|0; saves you one stroke of golf (saw this on some code-golf thread here)

Comment: -1 Very very ugly. Programming is about making other programmers understand what you do, NOT explictly obfuscating what you are trying to do.

Comment: +1 Programming is about making sure the programmer and the computer understand what you do, and idioms are perfectly appropriate if those conditions are met. All languages have them, even English. Idioms may be unfamiliar at first but as long as they are (1) memorable and (2) identifiable, they are wholly appropriate in a programmer's lexicon.

Comment: I think you need to appreciate this is game programming and this kind of thing is both common and required. Having good docs explaining performance tactics for your project is a good idea though. You should see some of the hoops required to minimize garbage collection in JVMs.

Comment: This is actually not a bad idea, but a code comment would be a good idea unless you are 100% sure your audience will understand your intent.

Comment: Note that this will not only truncate the number to its integer portion, it will truncate it to a signed 32-bit value. You can also use `>>>` to truncate to an unsigned 32-bit value.

Answer (score 5):

I found some good info @ 
http://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/bitwise-byte-foolish/

Apparently they perform very well these days. Why would you use them? Same reason you would anywhere else.

Comment: I'm 3 years late to the party, but thanks for linking the good read =)

Comment: @aschyiel well, im 10 years late.. party still on?

Answer (score 3):

I'd think it's up to the implementer to make an operator efficient or inefficient. For example, there's nothing that prevents a JavaScript implementer from making a JITting VM, which turns a bitwise op into 1 machine instruction. So there's nothing **inherently** slow about "the bitwise operators in JavaScript".

Comment: @Snarfblam  this 'theory' of improvement of javascript implementations has many practical precedents in the short history of javascript.  Also, and I'm not sure that is e.e.coli's point as well, the CPUs all support fast bitwise operation, so there is indeed nothing inherently slow about bitwise operation at this low level, so if for some reason javascript implementation had sloppily failed to map js bitwise ops to these efficient machine ops, this could be fixed easily, and more quickly if there was any indication that this issue is effectivley a bottleneck for most uses of js.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [NES emulator](http://benfirshman.com/projects/jsnes/) written in JavaScript - it seems to make plenty of use of bitwise operations.

Answer (score 2):

I am doubtful that bitwise operation are particularly slow in javascript.  Since such operations can map directly to CPU operations, which are themselves quite efficient, **there doesn't appear to be any inherent characteristic of bitwise operations that would force them to be irremediably slow in javascript**.
**Edit December 2015**:  I stand corrected! The performance hit that Javascript suffers in regards to bitwise operations comes from the need of converting from float to int and back (as all numeric variables in Javascript are stored as floating point values).  Thank you to Chad Schouggins for pointing that out.

Never the less, as indicated in several responses, there exist various applications of javascript which rely on bitwise operation (ex: crytography and graphics) and which are not particularly slow...  (see silky and Snarfblam on this page).  This suggests that while slower than C/C++ and other languages which translate directly bitwise ops to single native CPU instructions, bitwise operations are all that sluggish.

Let's never the less entertain the possibility that some particular reasons caused the various implementers of javascript hosts to implement bitwise ops in a fashion that makes these extremely slow, and **see if this even matters**...

Although javascript has been used for other purposes, **the most common use of this language in in providing user interface type of services**. 
BTW, I do not mean this in any pejorative way at all; performing these smart UI functions, and considering various constraints imposed on the language and also the loose adherence to standards, has required -and keeps requiring- talented javascript hackers.
The point is that in the context of UI-type requirements, the need for any *quantity* of bitwise operations susceptible of exposing the slowness of javascript in handling such operations is uncommon at best.  Consequently, for typical uses, **programmers should use bitwise operations where and if this approach seems to flow well with overall program/data and they should do so with little concern for performance issues.**  In the unlikely case of performance bottleneck arising from bitwise use, one can always refactor things, but one is better off staying clear from  early optimization.

The notable exception to the above is with the introduction of **canvas**, on modern browsers, we can expect that more primitive graphic functions will be required of javascript hosts, and such operations can require in some cases heavy doses of bitwise operations (as well as healthy does of math functions).  It is likely that these services will eventually be supported by way of javascript libraries (and even end-up as languages additions).  For such libraries the common smarts of the industry will have been put to use to figure out the most efficient approaches.  Furthermore and *if* indeed there is a weakness in javascript performance with bitwise ops, we'll get some help, for I predict that the javascript implementations on various hosts (browsers) will be modified to improve this particular area.   (This would follow the typical pattern of evolution of javascript, that we've seen over the years.)

Answer (score 1):

When speed is paramount, you can use them for bit-masking: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/storing_values/

Also, if you need to support Netscape 4, you'd use them to deal with Document.captureEvents(). Not that any respectable company would have you write JS for NS4...

Comment: Welcome to hell. you have two choices for your eternal suffering: Burn on a charcoal grill, or write JS for NS4.

Answer (score 1):

People do interesting things in JavaScript.

For example there are a lot of cryptography algorithms implemented in it (for various reasons); so of course bitwise operators are used.

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript in its Windows Scripting Host JScript incarnation, you might have cause to use bitwise operators to pick out flags in values returned from WMI or Active Directory calls. For example, the User Access value of a user's record in AD contains several flags packed into one long integer.

```
ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE = 0x00000002;

if (uac & ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE == ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE) {
  // user account has been disabled
}
```

Or someone's arbitrary table structure may contain such a field, accessible through ADO with JScript.

Or you may want to convert some retrieved data into a binary representation on any platform, just because:

```
BinaryData = "L";
BinaryString = BinToStr(BinaryData, ".", "x");

// BinaryString => '.x..xx..'
```

So there are numerous reasons why one might want to do bit manipulation in JavaScript. As for performance, the only way to know is to write it and test it. I suspect in most cases it would be perfectly acceptable, not significantly worse than any other of the multitude of inefficiencies these systems contain.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of bitwise operations are being benchmarked here: http://jsperf.com/rounding-numbers-down/3

However, feel free to create your own performance testcase on jsPerf!