# Using binary to compress boolean array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, binary, boolean

I am wondering if there is a way that allows me to store a boolean array efficiently. In my understanding, every boolean variable in JavaScript takes 1 byte or 8 bits to store. However, if I want to store a array of boolean value, 8 bits can store up to 8 boolean values actually. The rest 7 bits are wasted.

In language like C or Java, people can use bit operation like ">>", "~" to store boolean array into a int value. However, that does not work well in JavaScript since it works extremely slow in JavaScript because it needs to convert the floating number to int ([See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523061/performance-of-bitwise-operators-in-javascript)).

I also noticed **Buffer** in JavaScript which stores binary data directly. However, I cannot find a way to use it to store boolean array. I think **Buffer** are more focused on encoding stuff. For example, if I want to set the fifth bit of a boolean array to true, I can do `data |= 1<<4` but I cannot find a way to do so in Buffer.

Any solution?

Comment: "*it works extremely slow in JavaScript*" - don't be fooled by questions from '09 with answers from '12. JS engines have moved on, and optimising integer/bitwise arithmetic is one of the simplest things.

Comment: FWIW v8 has optimizations for "small" integers (SMIs). You can read about those limits [here](https://github.com/thlorenz/v8-perf/blob/master/test/boxing.js). You could use Buffers also, but since they work with bytes you would be limited to 8 boolean values per index.

Comment: To access the buffer, you need to use a [typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray), e.g. `Uint8Array`

Comment: @Bergi Ok, thanks. :) I should do benchmark next time

Comment: @SCLeo https://github.com/infusion/BitSet.js

Comment: @stdob-- I just do not understand why u guys love to write comments instead of answers. In this case, I cannot up vote you. ._.

Comment: @SCLeo Because it was not the answer, but it was a recommendation. This link solve your problem? :)

Comment: @stdob-- It did. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can use a Bit-Vector implementation](https://github.com/infusion/BitSet.js):

```
var bs = new BitSet;
bs.set(128, 1); // Set bit at position 128
console.log(bs.toString(16)); // Print out a hex dump with one bit set
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the accepted answer, there's also [`minimal-bit-array`](https://github.com/mikolalysenko/minimal-bit-array), which [`ndarray-bit`](https://github.com/scijs/ndarray-bit) is based on, both made by the creator of [`ndarray`](https://github.com/scijs/ndarray) itself. Very similar usage (from readme):

```
var x = new BitArray(100)
x.set(5, true)
console.log(x.get(4)) // Prints false
console.log(x.get(5)) // Prints true
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?
(Max index is 30):

```
function BoolArray(){
  this.arr = 0;
}

BoolArray.prototype.get = function(idx){
  return !!((this.arr >> idx) & 1)
}

BoolArray.prototype.set = function(idx, val){
  this.arr |= (val & 1) << idx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this amazing answer: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/optimizing-long-lists-of-yesno-values-with-javascript/

Convert the array of Boolean to 1’s and 0’s and join them as a string. For further optimization, you can represent 16 bit chunks as 1 UTF-16 character for 93% compression and store that string. It’s actually quite easy.