# jquery math with radio button and text field

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to build a calculator that does some simple math based on a number you input and a radio button you select.

I want to pre-populate the number and pre-select the radio button and show a sample outcome.

When I hard code the value of the text field it works until I try and change the new number then my output value flashes correctly and goes away. I know this is almost working but I can't seem to finish it off.

My thought is maybe I should be pre-populating the text field using jQuery but I'm not sure.

```
$(function() {
$(".calculate").change(function(){
var valone = $('#ms').val();
var valtwo = $('input:radio[name=ValTwo]:checked').val();

var total = ((valone * 1) * (valtwo * 1));
$('#Total').text(total);
});
}); 

<form>
        <dl>
            <dt><label for="spending">Monthly Spending</label></dt>
            <dd><input name="ValOne" id="ms" type="text" value="2500"></dd>
            <br /><br />
            <dt><label for="balance">Is your balance typically<br />above $5,000?</label></dt>
            <dd>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Yes <input name="ValTwo" type="radio" value=".02" class="calculate" checked='checked'>
                No  <input name="ValTwo" type="radio" value=".01" class="calculate">
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <input type="image" id="enter" value="open an account" src="images/btn-go.png">    
    </form>

<span  id="Total">50</span>
```

Comment: Not related to your problem. Using unary `+` operator is faster than `*`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665984/is-minus-zero-some-sort-of-javascript-performance-trick and http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/type_convert.html#tcNumber

Comment: Can you put this up somewhere that we can take a look.

Comment: I have it loaded up at http://maligndesign.com/calc/

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code to

```
function reCalc()
{
    var valone = $('#ms').val();
    var valtwo = $('input:radio[name=ValTwo]:checked').val();

    var total = ((valone * 1) * (valtwo * 1));
    $('#Total').text(total);
}

$('#ms').keyup(reCalc);
$('.calculate').change(reCalc);
```

will recalculate the total on each keypress in the spending field, and also on each change of the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
$('#Total').text(total);
```

to

```
$('#Total').html(total);
```