# What is the benefit of subtracting 0 from a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I saw a Javascript function that starts like this:

```
var _0xadf3 = function(_0x29ae0e, _0x3626db) {
_0x29ae0e = _0x29ae0e - 0x0;
var _0x5edbe5 = _0x4430[_0x29ae0e];
if (_0xadf3['ogYkVt'] === undefined) {
    (function() {
```

What is the purpose of the first line of code (_0x29ae0e = _0x29ae0e - 0x0;)? The first line of code takes the first variable of the function, _0x29ae0e, and subtracts 0 from it. Thus, it seems that you will just be left with the original value. This seems unnecessary, and I would like to understand the reason.

Comment: Converts the first variable to number in case it is a string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Subtracting Zero some sort of JavaScript performance trick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665984/is-subtracting-zero-some-sort-of-javascript-performance-trick)

Comment: @luk2302 I saw that before I posted here but the replies were not as clear as there are her. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtracting by zero is a way to force type-conversion.
From [Type-Conversion tutorial](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/type-conversion/#tcNumber)

> Any mathematical operator except the concatenation/addition operator will force type-conversion. So conversion of a string to a number might entail performing a mathematical operation on the string representation of the number that would not affect the resulting number, such as subtracting zero or multiplying by one.

Subtracting by `0x0` in this case performs a forced type-conversion on `_0x29ae0e` to convert it to hex