# Local Variables take 7x longer to access than global variables?

Tags: javascript, optimization, benchmarking, variable-caching

I was trying to benchmark the gain/loss of "caching" math.floor, in hopes that I could make calls faster.

Here was the test:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function()
{
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var k = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) k += Math.floor(9.99);
  var mathFloorTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;

  startTime = new Date().getTime();
  window.mfloor = Math.floor;
  k = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) k += window.mfloor(9.99);
  var globalFloorTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;

  startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var mfloor = Math.floor;
  k = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) k += mfloor(9.99);
  var localFloorTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;

  document.getElementById("MathResult").innerHTML = mathFloorTime;
  document.getElementById("globalResult").innerHTML = globalFloorTime;
  document.getElementById("localResult").innerHTML = localFloorTime;
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
Math.floor: <span id="MathResult"></span>ms <br />
var mathfloor: <span id="globalResult"></span>ms <br />
window.mathfloor: <span id="localResult"></span>ms <br />
</body>
</html>
```

My results from the test:

```
[Chromium 5.0.308.0]:  
Math.floor: 49ms  
var mathfloor: 271ms  
window.mathfloor: 40ms  

[IE 8.0.6001.18702]  
Math.floor: 703ms  
var mathfloor: 9890ms  [LOL!]  
window.mathfloor: 375ms   

[Firefox [Minefield] 3.7a4pre]
Math.floor: 42ms  
var mathfloor: 2257ms  
window.mathfloor: 60ms   

[Safari 4.0.4[531.21.10] ]
Math.floor: 92ms 
var mathfloor: 289ms 
window.mathfloor: 90ms 

[Opera 10.10 build 1893]
Math.floor: 500ms 
var mathfloor: 843ms 
window.mathfloor: 360ms

[Konqueror 4.3.90 [KDE 4.3.90 [KDE 4.4 RC1]]]
Math.floor: 453ms 
var mathfloor: 563ms 
window.mathfloor: 312ms
```

The variance is random, of course, but for the most part

In all cases [this shows time taken]:
[takes longer] mathfloor > Math.floor > window.mathfloor [is faster]

Why is this?  In my projects i've been using `var mfloor = Math.floor`, and according to my not-so-amazing benchmarks, my efforts to "optimize" actually slowed down the script by ALOT...

Is there any other way to make my code more "efficient"...?  I'm at the stage where i basically need to optimize, so no, this isn't "premature optimization"...

Comment: I might be reading this wrong, but your text labels looks like they're referring to the wrong things. Looks like they should be:
Math.floor: <span id="MathResult"></span>ms <br />
window.mathfloor: <span id="globalResult"></span>ms <br />
var mathfloor: <span id="localResult"></span>ms <br />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have these two variables labelled incorrectly:

```
var mathfloor: <span id="globalResult"></span>ms <br />
window.mathfloor: <span id="localResult"></span>ms <br />
```

@David's alternatives are worth looking into, as would some kind of memoisation.

Comment: I feel stupid now.  Thank you.  Could you explain why Window.mathfloor takes forever but Window.Math.floor doesn't?

Comment: I would guess it's because the globals are privileged in their lookup on the window object; you can optimise for them. This page http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/jkm3/ confirms your findings and suggests it's because the window object is crowded at the best of times.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your benchmarks do what they do.

But if you are going to call Math.floor often you can use this:

```
var num = 9.99;
var floored = ~~num; // 9
```

Not that `~~` will probably fail on strings (`var num = "9.99"`), numbers out of the 32 bit range, and negative numbers (`~~` will round up).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526682/why-is-javascripts-math-floor-the-slowest-way-to-calculate-floor-in-javascript) for a little more information.

---

**UPDATE**
Here is an [modified benchmark](http://jsbin.com/uxure3)

On Chrome i'm getting the local scope returning faster than Math.floor and the global scope. (window.mfloor) Note that I'm not referencing the global mfloor with the `window.` syntax as in the original benchmark.

So, I think your test has 2 issues (besides the variable name mix up mentioned in other answers). One being that you were running the loop on window.mfloor and the other being that you had a local variable with the same name as a global variable (this is just speculation).

Try the benchmark using the jsbin link i posted and get back to me.

---

here is my benchmark for the lazy:

```
window.onload = function(){

  var k = 0, i=0, n = 2000000,
  startTime = +(new Date);
  for(; i < n; ++i) k += Math.floor(9.99);
  var mathFloorTime = (new Date) - startTime;

  window.globalMfloor = Math.floor;
  k = i = 0;
  startTime = +(new Date);
  for(; i < n; ++i) k += globalMfloor(9.99);
  var globalFloorTime = (new Date) - startTime;

  var mfloor = Math.floor;
  k = i = 0;
  startTime = +(new Date);
  for(; i < n; ++i) k += mfloor(9.99);
  var localFloorTime = (new Date) - startTime;

  alert("Math.floor: " + mathFloorTime);
  alert("globalMfloor: " + globalFloorTime);
  alert("mfloor: " + localFloorTime);
};​
```

Comment: My question was targeted to be more in-general.  As in: why does accessing of local variables take forever =/ Math.floor was just an example.  Thomas Fuchs presented the ~~ thing in one of his optimization lectures, and yeah, it does cut down the time alot, but that isn't what i'm asking for

Comment: ok, I just wanted to mention it just in case. I'm curious about your question and am doing some benchmarks on my own. I'll update my answer if I find anything of interest.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**  Oops, I didn't read the answer about the field name mixup.  It turns out that, in Firefox, accessing a local variable was faster (took 80% as long) as accessing Math.floor, but accessing a global variable took 140% as long.

In my original answer, I postulated that local variables are harder to access than global ones because of closure processing and whatnot.  However, it seems to be the other way around.

Comment: Function local variables are searched for before global variables.