# How to cache images in Meteor?

Tags: ios, image, caching, meteor

I'm building a mobile app using Meteor. To allow for offline usage of the app, I want the app to be able to download a large-ish json file while online, then access the data in the json file, written to MongoDB, while offline.

This works fine. However, in the downloaded json file, there are plenty of references to online images that won't display in the app once the app is offline.

So, I want to be able to download (a selection of) the images referenced in the json file to the app, so that the app can access them even when offline.

(Downloading images could happen in the background for as long as a connection is available.)

There's an implementation of [imgCache.js](https://github.com/chrisben/imgcache.js/) [available on Atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com/chrisben/imgcache), which fails to initialize for me.

I suppose it's theoretically possible to individually load each image to a canvas, save the canvas content to MongoDB, then load the content when needed. Info on some of this is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/Canvas.html). But, this feels rather convoluted and, if really feasible, I would expect someone to have done this before with success.

How can I do achieve caching of images for offline use in Meteor?

Comment: I do this way in my mobile app, I use 'grounddb' and I'll save images to user's device using `cordova filetransfer` plugin and then save the local url and remote url details to seperate collection in ground  db and then use it whenver needed.

Comment: Are you doing this in a Meteor app? Would you be able to give a barebones example?

Answer (score 1):

So, you've probably already read [this article](http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag) about application cache.

If the images are static, you can just include them in the manifest.  Be sure you understand the manifest and cache expirations (see the article).

If the images are dynamic, you'll find some techniques to [store images in local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717189/storing-jpg-files-in-local-storage)

If that's the case, this may be [what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page).

Comment: Thanks. This looks promising. I will specifically try out the library mentioned in one of the answers: https://github.com/moledet/jQueryImageCaching

Comment: The jQuery image caching didn't work for me. Locally and remote, I was presented with an error for each caching request: "SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent."

Comment: @MastaBaba this is a hard problem, you really need to understand browsers and the specs to win.