# jquery click function select & deselect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help with this jQuery code. I have a SVG map, and I need a to select a country with one click, and deselect it with another one. Can somebody help me ? :)
This is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {




 $("path").mouseover(function() {
     $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');$(this).attr({
    fill: "#FF0000",
    stroke: "#00FF00"
     });
     $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    })
 .mouseout(function(){
     if(!$(this).data('clicked')){
       $(this).attr({
    fill: "#FFFFFF",
    stroke: "#eee"
    });
    } 
  });


$("path").click(function() {
$(this).attr({
    fill: "#FF0000",
    stroke: "#00FF00"
});
$(this).data('clicked', true); 

});

});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Comment: You don't explain what is the problem or error you are getting, this is a poor question, just pasting code.

Answer (score 2):

The most emphatic approach would be to use: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: I have solved this problem with custom code before, but I didn't know about 'toggle()' until today. Why is it marked deprecated, though?

Comment: whoops...that's not too visible on the doc page.  Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911577/jquery-click-toggle-between-two-functions

Answer (score 0):

You might be adding some class when selecting and then removing the class when deselecting

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
     <input type='text' id="text1" onclick='javascript:toggleClass(this)' />
 </body>
 </html>
 <script src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script language='javascript' type="text/javascript">


 function toggleClass(item) {

    if ($(item).hasClass('select')) {
        $(item).removeClass('select').addClass('deselect');
    }
    else {
        $(item).removeClass('deselect').addClass('select');
    }

  }
 </script>
```