# JQuery toggle() doesn't work in 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I tried to use Jquery toggle event as following:

```
$("button:eq(2)").toggle(function(){
                                $(this).attr("style","background:red");},
                                function(){
                                $(this).attr("style","background:blue");},
                                function(){
                                $(this).attr("style","background:green");}
                        );
```

It could run properly if using jquery v1.6.1,But once changed to jquery latest version v1.9.1,it would throw followng exception:

**Uncaught TypeError: Property 'function (){
$(this).attr("style","background:blue");}' of object # is not a function**

Does anybody know this is caused by jquery bug or just because of the coding has some problem?

Comment: This version of `.toggle` was removed from jQuery 1.9: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed. You can have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4911577/218196) for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was removed in jQuery 1.9. - http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/