# jQuery deprecated '.toggle()'. Seeking alternative method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Since `.toggle()` was [deprecated](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11786) from jQuery, I am looking for a new simple solution which will enable me to create a "Read more" button which slides down a paragraph whilst changing the button text to "Read less".

I have put together this working code:

```
var moreText = "Read more";
var lessText = "Read less";

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.readmorebtn").text(moreText);
    $("a.readmorebtn").toggle(function () {
        $("a.readmorebtn").text(lessText);
        $("p.more").slideToggle(0);
    },

    function () {
        $("a.readmorebtn").text(moreText);
        $("p.more").slideToggle(0);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/approach/gDvyR/

You'll see in the fiddle that 'Migrate 1.1.0' is checked on the options on the left, which is the only way to make `.toggle()` work in this way with this (newest) version of jQuery.

My question is, can you think of another way of performing the same function but without using `.toggle()` and Migrate?

Apologies if you feel this question has been answered elsewhere, but I keep finding hints at the workarounds being "relatively straightforward", without really seeing any definitive approaches. Unfortunately being new to jQuery it doesn't seem so straight forward to me!

Many, many thanks.

Comment: do you seek a general solution, or one for this specific case?

Comment: Hi Yoshi, one for this case would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911577/jquery-click-toggle-between-two-functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally think all the answers here are too elaborate for what you need. This should do the trick just fine and it works with multiple occurences. http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/gDvyR/5/

```
var moreText = "Read more",
    lessText = "Read less",
    moreButton = $("a.readmorebtn");

moreButton.click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text($this.text() == moreText ? lessText : moreText);
    $this.next("p.more").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: This is totally unnecessary change, but since in the 7th line, the `.text()` is always applied, you might as well just determine which text is applied inside `.text()`: `$this.text( $this.text() == moreText ? lessText : moreText );` -- http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/gDvyR/4/

Comment: @Joonas Good call. Edited. :)

Comment: This works great! Now I'll have to make sure I understand what's going on that is making it work. Thank you @BramVanroy and Joonas.

Comment: @Sam, I didn't want to clutter the answer, so I added some explanatory comments to explain what is going on with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/gDvyR/6/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic replacement  :

```
$.fn.toggleFuncs = function() {
    var functions = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
    _this = this.click(function(){
        var i = _this.data('func_count') || 0;
        functions[i%functions.length]();
        _this.data('func_count', i+1);
    });
}
```

You use it as you would use toggle :

```
$('something').toggleFuncs(f1, f2, f3);
```

**[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/QWSbV/)**

Comment: Thanks @dystroy. For some reason though, in your demonstration I get the "Read less" text appear after the second paragraph is closed. I'm not sure why this could be happening, the code seems to make sense to me.

Comment: @Sam I just inverted the two last lines to ensure the first function passed is the first one to be called.