# jQuery reverse animation on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Looked through a few of the existing questions and they helped me get this far, but still cannot get it working.

```
$('#languageSelctor').click(function()
{
    $('#languageList').toggle(function()
    {
        $(this).animate({"top": "20px"},500);
    },  function() 
    {
        $(this).animate({"top": "-100px"},500);
    });
});
```

Managed to put together the above code, but now it just does not work. So when someone clicks on languageSelctor, languageList needs to appear and then disappear if they click on languageList again.

Comment: `.toggle()` used in this manner is deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/toggle

Comment: `.toggle('slow')` or `.toggle(500)` should work, no?

Comment: the `top` value, if significant should be handled from CSS, not jquery, if possible. a normal `toggle()` with that should serve the purpose

Comment: This might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15085400/603568

Comment: Have a look at: http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/ it fades in and out the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#languageSelctor').click(function() {
    var $language = $('#languageList'),
        top = $language.css('top') === '-100px' ? '20px' : '-100px';
    $language.stop().animate({top: top}, 500);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this to hide and show the content.

```
$('#languageSelctor').click(function()
{
    $('#languageList').toggle();
});

$('#languageList').click(function()
{
    $(this).hide();
});
```

[**.toggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: why downvote.Please give the reason for me.See the requirement before giving a downvote