# How to stop a running function when another function is fired

Tags: performance, function

I want to pause/stop a running function below when the other function is firing.

```
function log(msg) {document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = msg + '<br/>';}

var a = function() {
    var j = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        log('A: ' + j++);
    },1000);
}

var b = function() {
    var j = 1001;
    setInterval(function() {
        log('B: ' + j++);
    },1000);
}

var b1 = document.getElementById('button1')
  , b2 = document.getElementById('button2');

b1.addEventListener('click', a, false);
b2.addEventListener('click', b, false);
```

Also, I want to prevent these functions from double fired (or fired multiple times) if I hit a button repeatedly.

Thank you,

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340426/jquery-pause-resume-timer-toggle)

Comment: No, that doesn't answer my question and I don't use jQuery. Thanks