# What use instead of toggleEvent for a .click function?

Tags: jquery

Since jQuery 1.9, **toggleEvent** do not exists anymore, so I am trying to do something like: when someone click at `.trigger`, the `div#map` get bigger, when click again, `div#map` get smaller.

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){ 
  $("#map").animate({height: '400px'}, 550, function() { $(".trigger").text("see small");
  });
}, function(){
  $("#map").animate({height: '205px'}, 250, function() { $(".trigger").text("see big");
  });
});
```

If I use "toggle" in 1.8.3 it works fine, but I want to run in 1.9.1 and I don't know how.

Example of the code running in 1.8.3: http://jsfiddle.net/EZ9My/

Comment: A quick search here would bring a dozen of duplicates.

Comment: You can easily create your own version of `toggleEvent`, as I have shown in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4911660/218196.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $(".trigger").click(function(){
     if($("#map").css('height') == '400px'){
       $("#map").stop().animate({height:'205px'},550);
       $(this).text("see big");
     };
     if($("#map").css('height') == '205px'){
        $("#map").stop().animate({height:'400px'},250);
         $(this).text("see small");
     };
 });
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/EZ9My/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
var isSmall = false;
var trigger = $(".trigger").click(function(){
    if (isSmall)
        $("#map").animate({height: '400px'}, 550, function() { trigger.text("see small"); });
    else
        $("#map").animate({height: '205px'}, 250, function() { trigger.text("see big"); });

    isSmall = !isSmall;
});
```