# jQuery - how to delegate a toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I provide a toggle for a dynamically created element?
My code does not work:

JS

```
          $("body").on('toggle', ".buttonA", function(){
              function() {
                  ..do stuff
              },
              function() {
                  .. revert stuff
              }
      });
```

Comment: [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/): version deprecated: 1.8, removed: 1.9

Comment: see --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/18287434#18287434

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click','.buttonA', function () {
var toggled = $(this).data('toggled');
$(this).data('toggled', !toggled);
if (!toggled) {
    //..do stuff
}
else {
   //.. revert stuff
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery,you can use .live() methods for binding a dynamically created element.

```
$('#hello').live("click", function() {
  alert( "Goodbye!" ); // jQuery 1.3+
});
```

I didn't use jQuery for a long time.So I don't know the method is valid or not.But it is very easy to write a new method to resolve this requirement.The more important thing is you bind the element whether or not.