# JQuery click after animate not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

When I first click on the `#menuIcon` div I want it to animate the `#menu` div `left: 0em` and then when I click on it a second time animate `#menu` to `left: -12em`.

The first part works but when I click again nothing happens. `#menuIcon` is a child of `#menu`, does this affect anything?

Here's my JS (adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911577/jquery-click-toggle-between-two-functions) question, the micro query plugin answer):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery.fn.clickToggle = function(a,b) {
        function cb(){
            [b,a][this._tog^=1].call(this);
        }
        return this.on("click", cb);
    };

    $("#menuIcon").clickToggle(function() {   
        $("#menu").animate({left: "0em"}, 500);
    }, function() {
        $("#menu").animate({left: "-12em"}, 500);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

As suggested by John S here's the relevant(I think) html:

```
<div id="menu">

    <div id="menuIcon">
        <div id="menuIcon1"></div>
        <div id="menuIcon2"></div>
        <div id="menuIcon3"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

And css:

```
#menu {
    width: 16em;
    height: calc(100% - 5em);
    background-color: blue;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -12em;
}

#menuIcon {
    height: 4em;
    width: 4em;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 12em;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: The JavaScript looks OK. You might need to show the relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: I think you're probably right @JohnS . I've added what I think is the relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e0rwty8y/), and it appears to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Might be easier just use an added class to toggle the direction:

```
$("#menuIcon").on("click", function() {  
     $this = $(this)

     if(!$this.hasClass("open"))
     {
         $("#menu").animate({left: "0em"}, 500);
         $this.addClass("open");
     }
     else
     {
        $("#menu").animate({left: "-12em"}, 500);
        $this.removeClass("open");
     }
 })
```

This isnt as clever as what you were trying but I think its a lot easier to read, and should work

Comment: It looks fine, but still the same problem @jlane09 think it's probably my html / CSS

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#menuIcon').toggle(
  function(){
   $("#menu").animate({left: "0em"}, 500);
  } , 
  function(){
   $("#menu").animate({left: "-12em"}, 500);
  }
);
```

Use the Jquery toggle function and will do the magic for you. Thanks

Comment: That version of the [JQuery `toggle()` function](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) was deprecated in v1.8 and removed in v1.9, so you would have to be including an old version of JQuery to use it.

Answer (score 0):

As John S said, my problem was not with the jQuery but with the rest of my HTML.

I had a div with that overlapped #menu when it was opened. I set #menu 's z-index to 2 and that worked.