# Toggle style of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At first time, when we click over the button, I want a script to change style of the span into color:#eee; and for second click, I want to change it into color:#000; and do this over and over again. How to toggle these styles of an element?
Is it possible to do, with normal JavaScript (no jQuery)?
I have found something at here:[jQuery click / toggle between two functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911577/jquery-click-toggle-between-two-functions)
But I don't know how to use jQuery.

```
<span class="blue">
Hi
</span>
<button>
Change
</button>
```

I want to toggle the class attribute, so that I could add my whole change-needed code into another class as class="red"
How to toggle style of this tag into class="red" and class="Blue" ?

Comment: Sorry. SO is not a code writing service. On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: You already know how to solve this, and you're linking to the solution right in your question...? Why even post this? It's going to be closed really fast.

Comment: @ChrisG because lack of knowledge in jQuery.

Comment: @Jishnuraj yeah... I'm aware of that. But you already know how to fix that, too! Learn jQuery. SO isn't the website you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```js
var span = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
function changeStyle() {
  if(span.style.color === 'red') {
    span.style.color = 'black';
  } else {
    span.style.color = 'red'
  }
}
```

```html
<span>
Hi
</span>
<button onclick="changeStyle()">
Change
</button>
```

### Update

*"Why isn't this code working? **code in comment**"*

There are few issues with your code. At first, your script should go after HTML tags, because when we are doing `var span = document.getElementById('span');`, the element with id `span` should be already defined, otherwise we will get `null`. To find other differences compare your code with code below:

```html
<style> .red { color:red; } .blue { color:blue; } </style>

<span class="red" id="span"> Hi </span> 
<button onclick="changeStyle()"> Change </button>

<script> 
var span = document.getElementById('span');
function changeStyle() {
  for(var i = 0; i < span.classList.length; i++) {
    if(span.classList[i].indexOf('red') >= 0) {
      span.classList.remove('red');
      span.classList.add('blue');
    } else { 
      span.classList.remove('blue');
      span.classList.add('red'); 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can I change the class attribute to class="red_class" and class="blue"?

Comment: It's code will be more easy, so that I could even toggle other styles with it.

Comment: @Jishnuraj, it's possible, just use `.classList.add('class-name')` and `.classList.remove('class-name')`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a CSS class. If you set up a class that contains the styling you want then you can simply toggle it on and off.

The Javascript for that would look something like this:

```
var elem = document.querySelector(yourElement);

elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
    elem.classList.toggle("className");
}
```

Comment: How to toggle different class attributes as class="red" and class="blue" ?