# Toggle method without show/hide option

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to use `.toggle()` method but not for show and hide purposes?

For example, when I click on a certain div I would like to animate it's position
`$(div).animate({"left":"+=50px"});` and then on the second click to return the div on the same position `$(div).animate({"left":"-=50px"})`.

I know there is other solution but I would like to achieve this with `.toggle()` without hiding an showing the div.  Any ideas?

Comment: you can use `click()` with `if`/`else`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#myDiv").toggle(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
       left:"+=50"
    }, 500);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        left:"-=50"
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
#myDiv{
background-color:black;
width:100px;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
left:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

hope this answer your question. However, jQuery 1.9 and newer do not allow this feature.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  But I don't like to use Class with CSS. I would like to achieve this with poor jQuery. Any ideas ???

Answer (score 0):

there is no toggle function using click since 1.9 . But you can still doing this using two ways:

[for more explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911577/jquery-click-toggle-between-two-functions)

```js
$(function(){
  //basic method
  var clicked = false;
  $('#mydiv1').click(function(){
    if(clicked){
      clicked = false;
      $(this).animate({"left":"+=50px"});
    }else{
      clicked=true;
      $(this).animate({"left":"-=50px"});
    }
  });
  
  //create new function like old built-in function
  $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {
        var funcs = [func1, func2];
        this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
        this.click(function() {
            var data = $(this).data();
            var tc = data.toggleclicked;
            $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
            data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
        });
        return this;
    };
  
  $('#mydiv2').clickToggle(function(){
      $(this).animate({"left":"+=50px"});
    }, function(){
      $(this).animate({"left":"-=50px"});
  });
  
});
```

```css
#mydiv1{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}

#mydiv2{
background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="mydiv1"></div>
  <div id="mydiv2"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Excellent - create new function sample.