# Flooring numbers in JavaScript: ~~n, n|0 or Math.floor(n)?

Tags: javascript, integer

I've recently discovered some other ways to remove the fractional part of numeric values in JavaScript other than `Math.floor(n)`, specifically the double bitwise NOT operator `~~n` and performing a bitwise or with 0 `n|0`.

I'd like to know what are the difference between these approaches and what the different scenarios are where one method is recommended over another.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526682/why-is-javascripts-math-floor-the-slowest-way-to-calculate-floor-in-javascript , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049677/how-does-x0-floor-the-number-in-javascript

Comment: eventually, there will be no difference as browsers evolve, see the consistent performance of chrome http://jsperf.com/math-floor-vs-math-round-vs-parseint/41 , it's better write maintainable code

Comment: @ajax333221 I just love how the IE entry looks like it is missing data ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be clear to the next person looking at your code and use `Math.floor()`.

[The performance gain of 1%-40%](http://jsperf.com/js-floors) isn't really worth it, so don't make your code confusing and hard to maintain.

Comment: (So they don't have to ask "What does n|0 mean?" on SO...)

Comment: @pst you probably meant _repost_ instead of _ask_

Answer (score 7):

The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers:

```
Math.floor(2147483648) // 2147483648
2147483648 | 0         // 2147483648
~~2147483648           // 2147483648

Math.floor(2147483649) // 2147483649
2147483649 | 0         // -2147483647
~~2147483649           // -2147483647
```

So use Math.floor();

Answer (score 2):

(I entirely agree with josh's answer: favor clear maintainable code.)

Here is an explanation on the other bit-wise approaches:

The bit-wise operators work because they *only* operator on 32-bit (signed) integers but numbers in JavaScript are all IEEE-754 values. Thus, there is an internal conversion (*truncation*, not floor!) that happens to operands for bit-wise operators.

The applied bit-wise operation (e.g. `n<<0`, `~~n` or `n|0`) then *acts as an identity function* which "does nothing" to the converted values: that is, all of these approaches rely on the same conversion applied to bit-wise operands.

Try `n` as a negative number or a value outside of [-2<sup>31</sup>, 2<sup>31</sup>-1]:

```
(-1.23|0)            // -1
Math.floor(-1.23)    // -2

var x = Math.pow(2, 40) + .5
x|0                  // 0
Math.floor(x)        // 1099511627776
```

Happy coding.