# How do I get an onclick to be reversed on a second click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a program where users select their availability. I have a mouse over color, but I would like that color to be confirmed on click. The only problem with the below solution is that upon a second click the  isn't reset. How do I get it to reset?

```
<td onclick="javascript:this.style.background = '#000000';">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change an element's CSS class with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Comment: You need a conditional check to determine if a color is applied or not. Here's a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/mun8y/) that uses a ternary operator to check. However, it probably makes more sense to use a CSS class and just add/remove that (which specifies the styles needed).

Answer (score 1):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/yavuz/1/edit)**

```
var $table = document.getElementById('myTable'),
    $td = $table.getElementsByTagName('td');

function fnToggle(){
  var io = this.io ^= 1; // Toggler
  this.style.backgroundColor = io ? "#000" : "transparent" ;
}

// Assign click handler (toward fnToggle) to all our TD elements
for(var i=0; i<$td.length;) $td[i++].onclick = fnToggle;
```

Read more about the use of `(?:)` [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
Read more about the use of `^=` **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654057/where-would-i-use-a-bitwise-operator-in-javascript/#answer-22061240)** (+ [bonus reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators))