# How to change text in HTML by clicking

Tags: javascript, html

```js
    function diffSign(div) {
      var sign = document.getElementById(div.id);
      if (XXXXX) {
        XXXXX
      } else {
        XXXX
      }
    }
```

```html
<div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo@(i.tostring)" id="Sign@(i.ToString)" onclick=diffSign(this)>+</div>
```

I want to change + sign to - and can change back!
THX

Answer (score 1):

The function's `div` Argument is already representing `this` by reference.

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/doqaxa/1/edit)**

```
function diffSign(div){
    if (div.innerHTML === '+') {   // If has "+"
        div.innerHTML = '-';       // Set as "-"
    } else {                       // else? well...
        div.innerHTML = '+';
    }
}
```

Or you can do it also like: **[jsBin demo using bitwise XOR (^=) and Ternary Operator(?:)](http://jsbin.com/doqaxa/2/edit)**

```
function diffSign(div) {      
   div.innerHTML = (div.io^=1) ? '-' : '+' ; 
}
```

<sub>https://stackoverflow.com/a/22061240/383904</sub>

Comment: Not worth a -1, but there's no reason to obfuscate your code like this. The comment you included doesn't really explain what the code does, either.

Answer (score 1):

```
function diffSign(div) {
  var sign = document.getElementById(div.id);
  sign.innerText = (sign.innerText === "+") ? "-" : "+";
}
```

but if you pass in the div, why would you search it again?

```
function diffSign(div) {
  div.innerText = (div.innerText === "+") ? "-" : "+";
}
```

would work too if the `div` parameter is the real `div`...
make sure this `div` has nothing other than the `+` or the `-` signs..

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function diffSign(div) {
    var sign = document.getElementById(div.id);
    if (sign.innerHTML == '+') {
        sign.innerHTML = '-';
    } else {
        sign.innerHTML = '+';
    }
}
```

```html
<div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo@(i.tostring)" id="Sign@(i.ToString)" onclick=diffSign(this)>+</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since div is the actual DOM element and a javascript object you can use it directly and add properties to it dynamically.

```
function diffSign(div) {
   //Add a new property to maintain the element's state on the first call, toggle it on subsequent calls
   div.useMinus = !div.useMinus;
   //set the text based on the current state.
   div.innerHTML = (div.useMinus ? '-' : '+');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use document.getElementById.innerHTML = "your new text"........ to change text.

Comment: That's changing the entire HTML document, not specific text