# Jquery animation on click

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate

I have called several animations to occur when a button is clicked. I want to toggle these animations, so that the elements return to their starting positions when clicked for a second time.

Here is my script:

```
$("span.click").click(function() {
  $(".map").animate(
    {"opacity": "1"}, 200);
});

$("span.click").click(function() {
  $(".navigation").animate(
    {"bottom": "-100px"}, 200);
});

$("span.click").click(function() {
  $(".click").animate(
    {"bottom": "150px"}, 200);
});
```

As you can see, three animations are occurring. What sort of if/else statement needs to be put into place in order to create reversible animations?

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6arjhkzc/2/

Comment: Don't you find this example somewhat simpler (to start from) http://jsfiddle.net/6arjhkzc/3/

Comment: Hold booleans which represent the current state, and check if it was animated each time. if it was, do the reverse. :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I just separated each function to clearly lay it out.

Comment: @A.Abramov I'm very new to query so I'm not sure how to do that at all

Comment: @AustinBranham Roko's answer is exacly what I said. Learn from it. :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thank you very much!!! Huge help

Comment: @AustinBranham you're welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6arjhkzc/4/)***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("span.click").click(function() {

        var io = this.io ^= 1; // Simple I/O toggler

      $(".map").animate({"opacity": io ? 1 : 0}, 200);
      $(".navigation").animate({"bottom": io ? -100 : -150}, 200);
      $(".click").animate({"bottom": io ? 150 : 100}, 200);
    });
});
```

store `1` or `0` inside the clicked button `io` property (used as Boolean since 0 evaluates as `false`).
Than using some Conditional Operator `?:` you can toggle the desired values.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22061240/383904

If you're not confortable with the bitwise XOR operator `^` as toggler, you can always use a standard *flip-flap* negation (***[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6arjhkzc/5/)***):

```
var io = this.io = !this.io;
```

Comment: How can you do a css transformation with this IO toggler? Say if I wanted to scale something up on click, I've tried this code but it does not work:

        $(this).animate({"transform","scale": io ? 1 : 1.5}, 100);

Comment: @AustinBranham almost like that, you have just a typo (missing `:` instead of `,`), Also, **animation does not apply to CSS transform. use CSS instead!!!** also in CSS it's like `scale(1.5)` so in jQuery it's the same: `$(this).css({transform : "scale("+ (io ? 1 : 1.5) +")" }, 100);` >> note the `:` and how I embraced the io stuff into `()` using string concatenation +. Also note that 100 is a really quick animation, I'd suggest to use min 230 for a better UX

Comment: Thank you very much. I had also tried several combinations with CSS instead of animation, but couldn't get it to work. That makes sense how io is embraced within the parentheses. If you don't mind answering, what are the function of the + signs outside of the io? String concatenation?

Comment: @AustinBranham Yes. When concatenating Strings with JS code, if you're a beginner first write the expected string: `"scale()"` than if you need a variable inside the () than write: `"scale("+ someThing +")"` now you've concatenated `someThing` variable withing the strings. If you need instead of `someThing` to do more advanced stuff, to avoid messing with + as cncatenator and + as addition simply wrap your logic inside `()` like `"scale("+ (a+b-c) +")"` or as we need to: `"scale("+ ( io ? 1 : 1.5 ) +")"` using a Conditional operator (?:)

Comment: is there a way to use the io toggler with percentage based values. For example: changing an absolutely positioned elements left or right positioning: $("example").css({"left": io ? 0% : 100%}, 230);

Comment: @AustinBranham yes, simply use quotes: `io ? "0%" : "100%"`

Comment: Yes, I realized that immediately after asking the question. Thanks again, you've been a big help.