# Interchange divs colors black and white on each clicks using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I click on a button, 
the color of the first div changes to black from white and the color of the second div changes to white from black, if I click  on that button the vice-versa happens.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Need to share your html and the js you have tried

Comment: Please, always show your basic HTML, CSS and JS code you attempted and explain what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toggleClass()` to acheive this.

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").click(function(){
        $('div').toggleClass('black , white')
    });
});
```

```css
.square{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.black{
  background-color:black;
  
}
.white{
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="square black"></div>
<div class="square white"></div>
<input type="button" value="Change">
```

Comment: Always glad to hear that `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery's `.toggleClass()`

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
  $("#a, #b").toggleClass("black");
});
```

```css
div{width:200px; height:50px; background: #ccc;}
.black{background:#000;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK ME</button>
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b" class="black"></div>
```

Using **bitwise XOR** `^` to remember the button state:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22061240/383904

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
  var io = this.io ^= 1;
  $("#a").css({background: io ? "#ccc" : "#000"});
  $("#b").css({background: io ? "#000" : "#ccc"});
});
```

```css
div{width:200px; height:50px; background:#000;}
#b{background:#ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK ME</button>
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

---

Using JS's `Array.prototype.reverse()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

```js
var colors = ["#000","#ccc"];
$("button").on("click", function(){
  $("#a").css({background: colors.reverse()[0] });
  $("#b").css({background: colors[1] });
});
```

```css
div{width:200px; height:50px; background:#000;}
#b{background:#ccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK ME</button>
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
```

Here's an additional reading if you want to use functions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21520499/383904

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toggleClass() {
  $(".main div").toggleClass("black , white");
}
```

```css
       .main {
         background-color: lightblue;
         height: 50px;
         width: 50px;
       }
       .black {
         color: #000;
       }
       .white {
         color: #fff;
       }
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="black">first</div>
  <div class="white">second</div>
</div>
<button onclick="toggleClass();">Toggle</button>
```