# JavaScript: Hide and Show Menu Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

```
var Menu = function() {
    state = 0;
}
Menu.prototype.click = function() {
    if (this.state == 1) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#collapse-menu").click(function(){
                $("#list-navbar").show(500);
                this.state = 0;
            });
        });
    } else {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#collapse-menu").click(function(){
                $("#list-navbar").hide(500);
                this.state = 1;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

How can I instantiate the class on the page load and just call the function `click` onclick event, keeping the class instantiated?

Comment: What's this code all about? I mean what's that `Menu` and it's `state` for?

Comment: It's a collapse menu. If state is equals 1 it means it's hidden and I want to show if the user click on the button. If it's equals 0, it means it's being displayed and I want to hide if the user click the button.

Comment: Note that you don't need to nest your `$(document).ready()` handlers. You can remove those lines.

Comment: @Chittolina sorry, had to fix my code, there was a flaw ;) please take review action to match changes.

Comment: Thanks. It's working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Menu = function() {
  this.state = 0;
};

Menu.prototype.click = function() {
  var that = this;   // our Menu object

  $("#collapse-menu").click(function(){
    that.state ^= 1; // Toggles 1,0,1... values
    $("#list-navbar")[that.state?"hide":"show"](500);
  });
};


jQuery(function( $ ) { // DOM ready here

  var m = new Menu();  // New Menu instance
  m.click();           // init clicks on #collapse-menu

});
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/jaletu/4/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

about `^` as toggler: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22061240/383904