# What does the '|' operator do in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
2 | 3 //Output is 3
7 | 9 //Output is 15
```

I tried `2 | 3` in the console and I got an output of `3`. When I did `7 | 9`, the output is `15`. How does it work?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are bitwise operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276706/what-are-bitwise-operators), [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: See also: [Where would I use a bitwise operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654057/where-would-i-use-a-bitwise-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

It is the `OR` operator used for Bitwise Operations.

**Example :**

5 | 1

**It will be the same as** 0101 | 0001

**Result**: 0101 = 5

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp).