# Choosing values for constants

Tags: constants, bit-manipulation, hex

One thing I've never really understood is why in many libraries, constants are defined like this:

```
public static final int DM_FILL_BACKGROUND = 0x2;
public static final int DM_FILL_PREVIOUS = 0x3;
public static final int TRANSPARENCY_MASK = 1 << 1;
public static final int TRANSPARENCY_PIXEL = 1 << 2;
```

What's up with the 0x and << stuff? Why aren't people just using ordinary integer values?

Comment: In what way is `0x2` *not* an “ordinary integer value”? It is completely normal. As for `1 << 1`, of course it’s an expression rather than a single value, but its result is still an “ordinary integer value”.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bit shifting of `1` is usually for situations where you have non-exclusive values that you want to store.

For example, say you want to be able to draw lines on any side of a box. You define:

```
LEFT_SIDE   = 1 << 0  # binary 0001 (1)
RIGHT_SIDE  = 1 << 1  # binary 0010 (2)
TOP_SIDE    = 1 << 2  # binary 0100 (4)
BOTTOM_SIDE = 1 << 3  # binary 1000 (8)
                               ----
                               0111 (7) = LEFT_SIDE | RIGHT_SIDE | TOP_SIDE
```

Then you can combine them for multiple sides:

```
DrawBox (LEFT_SIDE | RIGHT_SIDE | TOP_SIDE) # Don't draw line on bottom.
```

The fact that they're using totally different bits means that they're independent of each other. By `OR`ing them you get `1 | 2 | 4` which is equal to `7` and you can detect each individual bit with other boolean operations (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746613/bitwise-operation-and-usage/1746642#1746642) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276706/what-are-bitwise-operators/276715#276715) for an explanation of these).

If they were defined as 1, 2, 3 and 4 then you'd probably either have to make one call for each side or you'd have to pass four different parameters, one per side. Otherwise you couldn't tell the difference between `LEFT and RIGHT` (`1 + 2 = 3`) and `TOP` (`3`), since both of them would be the same value (with a simple addition operation).

The `0x` stuff is just hexadecimal numbers which are easier to see as binary bitmasks (each hexadecimal digit corresponds exactly with four binary digits. You'll tend to see patterns like `0x01`, `0x02`, `0x04`, `0x08`, `0x10`, `0x20` and so on, since they're the equivalent of a single `1` bit moving towards the most significant bit position - those values are equivalent to binary `00000001`, `00000010`, `00000100`, `00001000`, `00010000`, `00100000` and so on.

> *Aside:* Once you get used to hex, you rarely have to worry about the `1 << n` stuff. You can instantly recognise `0x4000` as binary `0100 0000 0000 0000`. That's less obvious if you see the value 16384 in the code although some of us even recognise *that* :-)

Comment: Well said.  I like the 1 << BitNo format for flags because you know which bit it is by looking at the definition.  I have a generic snippet that is defined as     <FlagsAttribute()> _
    Public Enum _Flag As Integer
 with 32 predefined flags.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding `<<` stuff: this in my preferred way.

When I need to define the constant with 1 in the bit 2 position, and 0 in all other bits, I can define it as `4`, `0x4` or `1<<2`. `1<<2` is more readable, to my opinion, and explains exactly the purpose of this constant.

BTW, all these ways give the same performance, since calculations are done at compile time.

Comment: `1<<2` may well be more readable. It's certainly more _accurate_, given that the value is `4`, not `7` :-)

Comment: I don't believe! Of course, 4. Never mix beer and programming!