# What are the | and ^ operators used for?

Tags: c#, .net, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are bitwise operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276706/what-are-bitwise-operators)

Recently I came across a few samples that used the | and ^ operator. I am guessing these are  `or` and `negation` operators.

So what actually do these operators stands for?

Comment: Why is this voted for closure

Comment: @TomTom: Seriously, read a language spec??? Who the hell does that.

Comment: @TomTom, I will take it as feedback if you can elaborate it a bit. Do you mean I should 1st read all the Specs and Concepts and then start for develoment

Comment: @Chris, if its a dupe, then find the dupe, and the question is answered.

Comment: People were upset, Subhen, that english doesn't seem to be your native language. They were reacting to the typo in the title.

Comment: Well, here it is - if you dont know the language, you make a piss poor developer to start with. It takes not even a day to read the C# language spec from start to finish.

Comment: Take a look at [What are bitwise operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276706/what-are-bitwise-operators).

Comment: @Ian: i didn't read the C# spec till well after i had learned to code in it (and BTW: a day? seriously? that's crazy, and i read *fast*), and i daresay i was a decent developer, if not great.

Comment: @RCIX i think you meant the comment below mine.

Comment: @Ian yea i did, sorry :)

Comment: i think cross linking as a dupe to javascript is a bad idea. c# != javascript.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you apply it to integral types, they are bitwise or and xor operator. 
However if you apply them to boolean types, they are logical or and xor. 
Look at an explanation of [or operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx(v=VS.100).aspx) and [xor operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1(v=VS.100).aspx)

You can get more details on boolean operations from the wikipedia [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Truth_table_for_all_binary_logical_operators)

Answer (score 26):

- `|` = (bitwise/non-short-circuiting) "or"
- `^` = "xor"

and for info, "not" (bitwise negation) is `~`

Answer (score 8):

MSDN has documentation on all the C# operators at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx

---

EDIT - Jon B commented that a relevant quote from the linked documentation would be useful.

`|` is the [Logical OR operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx).

> Binary | operators are predefined for the integral types and bool. For integral types, | computes the bitwise OR of its operands. For bool operands, | computes the logical OR of its operands; that is, the result is false if and only if both its operands are false.

`^` is the [Logical XOR operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx).

> Binary ^ operators are predefined for the integral types and bool. For integral types, ^ computes the bitwise exclusive-OR of its operands. For bool operands, ^ computes the logical exclusive-or of its operands; that is, the result is true if and only if exactly one of its operands is true.

Comment: -1 Posting a link to docs isn't an answer.

Comment: @Jon B, so you usually like to repeat things over and over again? Why not use a great resource which explains it instead of re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: @Filip - SO is a collection of programming questions and answers meant to outlast other websites and survive link changes on sites like MSDN. Posting a link is fine, but there needs to be a relevant quote

Comment: Actually it is. Any programmer worth a cent should know how to read langague specifications.

Comment: Stop()!!! using System.Hammertime.

Comment: +1 @Flip. SO is meant to contain answers to questions, in the same way Wikipedia contains content. A wikipedia entry that only contains a link to off-site content is not an entry.

Comment: I think a link to the msdn docs without explanation is fine.  Stackoverflow should not become (merely) msdn documentation quotes.

Answer (score 2):

they are logical bitwise operators

| is a Or [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx)

^ is XOR [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

With integral types, | is a bitwise or, ^ a bitwise xor and for completeness & is a bitwise and.

With boolean types, | is a boolean or, ^ a boolean xor and & a boolean &.

In comparison, || is a short-circuit boolean or - if the first operand evaluates as true the second operand isn't evaluated. && is a short-circuit boolean and - if the first operand is false, the second isn't evaluated. There is no short-circuit ^ because there is no case where the second need not be evaluated.

|| and && are more often used than | and & in boolean cases as there is normally at least a tiny efficiency gain and never a loss. However if the right-hand operand had a side-effect that it was important to trigger in all cases, then | or & would be the one to use. In practice this is rare, and a bad smell (if the side-effect is important, it should be evaluated in a separate expression to make the purpose clearer).

Edit: A source of potential confusion, is that in some other languages integral types can be used as booleans (e.g. you can do `if(53)` and it's the same as `if(true)`) this makes the distinctions between the above operators quite different: They're the same if a "purely" boolean type is used (that has only true and false as its possible values) but not otherwise. C# deliberately doesn't allow boolean operations on integral types precisely to prevent the possibilities for mistakes that exist in such languages.

Answer (score -6):

`^`   Logical XOR

`|`   Logical OR

**update**

in c# its logic operations too:

```
    Console.WriteLine(true ^ false);  // logical exclusive-or
    Console.WriteLine(false ^ false); // logical exclusive-or
```

Comment: -1 Neither of these are logical operators. They're both BitWise...and you mixed XOR and OR.

Comment: aside from getting XOR and OR backwards the MSDN article listed above from emddudley list them both as Logical

Comment: Michael, Logical or operator || C/C++, note at bottom of this site(explains difference between logical and bitwise)  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/logore.htm

Comment: @Meakins: This question is about C#, not C/C++ where you link makes perfectly sense. In C# `|` and `^` can both be logical and bitwise.

Comment: ok, http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html States that                                                                    Bitwise
&   |   ^   ~   <<   >>

Logical
&&   ||   &   |   ^   !

Comment: @Meakins, @Justin Niessner: I don't think it is correct to regard bitwise and logical as contrary concepts. In fact they are orthogonal, i.e. *bitwise* actually means that the *logical* operation is applied on bit level. No matter how you see it, it is always a *logical* AND, OR, or XOR operation.

Comment: I agree that deep down they are almost alike with one exception, The or will happen the same while the and will not as far as returning a boolean is concerned.