# In c# what does the ^ character do?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What are the | and ^ operators used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735623/what-are-the-and-operators-used-for)

and

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [C# - what does the unary ^ do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60502615/c-sharp-what-does-the-unary-do)

In c# what does the ^ character do?

Comment: An additional usage of "^" in C#, or which at least appears throughout .NET documentation without any explanation, is the "handle to object operator." This is a C++ thing that marks an object for garbage collection so you don't have to worry about memory mgt yourself. It's all over MSDN .NET docs e.g. `SomeMethod(String^, IDictionary<String^, Object^>^)`, but is not actually explained anywhere. The only thing that comes up in Google or SE regarding "^" in C# is this answer of "XOR", which is completely different. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk97tc08.aspx

Comment: See also [what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is binary [`XOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx) operator.

> Binary ^ operators are predefined for
>   the integral types and bool. For
>   integral types, ^ computes the bitwise
>   exclusive-OR of its operands. For bool
>   operands, ^ computes the logical
>   exclusive-or of its operands; that is,
>   the result is true if and only if
>   exactly one of its operands is true.

Answer (score 8):

The ^ charater, or 'caret' character is a bitwise XOR operator.
e.g.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Demonstrate XOR for two integers.
        int a = 5550 ^ 800;
        Console.WriteLine(GetIntBinaryString(5550));
        Console.WriteLine(GetIntBinaryString(800));
        Console.WriteLine(GetIntBinaryString(a));
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Repeat.
        int b = 100 ^ 33;
        Console.WriteLine(GetIntBinaryString(100));
        Console.WriteLine(GetIntBinaryString(33));
        Console.WriteLine(GetIntBinaryString(b));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns binary representation string.
    /// </summary>
    static string GetIntBinaryString(int n)
    {
        char[] b = new char[32];
        int pos = 31;
        int i = 0;

        while (i < 32)
        {
            if ((n & (1 << i)) != 0)
            {
                b[pos] = '1';
            }
            else
            {
                b[pos] = '0';
            }
            pos--;
            i++;
        }
        return new string(b);
    }
}

^^^ Output of the program ^^^

00000000000000000001010110101110
00000000000000000000001100100000
00000000000000000001011010001110

00000000000000000000000001100100
00000000000000000000000000100001
00000000000000000000000001000101
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/xor

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at MSDN [^ Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's the [logical XOR operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx).