# C# - what does the unary ^ do?

Tags: c#, syntax, operators

I have checked out some code and I got an error ('invalid expression term "^"' to be exact) in the line

```cs
// choices is a regular array
return choices[^1];
```

I have never seen a unary caret operator (I am only aware of the XOR operator, but that one obviously takes two operands). Does this operator exist and if so, what does it do?

Note: The site https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-operators mentions a unary caret operator in the precedence table but it does not explain what it does.

Comment: Lets visit the documentation [Index from end operator ^](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#index-from-end-operator-) Which part don't you understand ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#index-from-end-operator-

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Unary `^` is the "index from end" operator, introduced in C# 8.0. `choices[^1]` is equivalent to `choices[choices.Length - 1]`.

See [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#index-from-end-operator-) for additional details.

Answer (score 1):

In arrays it is called "Index from end operator" and is available from C# 8.0. As it says ... it indicates the element position from the end of a sequence.

In the second case, `^` plays the role of **Logical exclusive OR operator**. Being a binary operator, it needs two members (`x ^ y`), because it is doing an operation on them.
As an example:

```
Console.WriteLine(true ^ true);    // output: False
Console.WriteLine(true ^ false);   // output: True
Console.WriteLine(false ^ true);   // output: True
Console.WriteLine(false ^ false);  // output: False
```