# C++ - Vertical Line Operator. What does it do?

Tags: c++, operators

When you're passing flags to a function, what does using the operator '|' do and what is its proper name? How would I implement this in my own functions? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The answer is on every operator precedence chart known to man.

Comment: This is very fundamental.  If you don't know it you should have a ready reference (book or bookmark) to look details about the basic language.  You shouldn't need to ask here.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't thinking. Will research better next time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the | and ^ operators used for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735623/what-are-the-and-operators-used-for)

Answer (score 4):

It's bitwise OR. For example:

```
(1 | 2) == 3
(5 | 3) == 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends. The vertical line operator `|` draws one vertical line, pretty much like the horizontal line operator '-' draws one horizontal line. There are also the brethren `||` and `=` to draw two parallel vertical or horizontal lines, respectively:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

struct graphic
{
    void operator-(int n) {
        *std::fill_n(std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout), n, '-')++ = '\n';
    }
    void operator=(int n) {
        *std::fill_n(std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout), n, '=')++ = '\n';
    }
    void operator|(int n) {
        std::fill_n(std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, "\n"), n, '|');
    }
    void operator||(int n) {
        std::fill_n(std::ostream_iterator<char const*>(std::cout, "\n"), n, "||");
    }
};

int main()
{
    graphic g;
    g - 10;
    g = 10;
    g | 4;
    g || 4;
}
```