# Shift operator and bitwise or

Tags: c

I have four characters as
ch1,ch2,ch3,ch4. I am reading a binary file.
Que- What following code indicates?

```
int GetLong(FILE * hTTF) 
{
    int ch1 = getc(hTTF);
    int ch2 = getc(hTTF);
    int ch3 = getc(hTTF);
    int ch4 = getc(hTTF);

 if ( ch4 == EOF )
  return( EOF );

 return( (ch1<<24)|(ch2<<16)|(ch3<<8)|ch4 );
}
```

consider ch1='k',ch2='e',ch3='r',ch4='n';
Tell me output and why this is so?.
I am not understanding output value.
Que-What is this conversion (ch1<<24)|(ch2<<16)|(ch3<<8)|ch4 
What we achive by doing this?

Comment: Please explain the output you get and why you think it's wrong.  Or at least ask a more specific question.

Comment: Please read up on [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276706/what-are-bitwise-operators

Answer (score 4):

The fact that ch[1234] are characters is not relevant: they are just numeric values.

Just think it's something like this:

```
ch1 = 0x10;
ch2 = 0x20;
ch3 = 0x30;
ch4 = 0x40;
```

your output value will be hex value 0x10203040.

Answer (score 2):

What is output is a single int that has four chars inside of it.  You can think of it like this:

My four chars are: `0x00, 0x02, 0x53, 0xEF`

ch1 << 24 = 0x **00** 000000

ch2 << 16 = 0x00 **02** 0000

ch3 << 8 = 0x0000 **53** 00

ch4 = 0x000000 **EF**

Next with bitwise ors.

```
x | 0 = x
1 | x = 1
```

So:

```
0x00000000
0x00020000
0x00005300
0x000000EF
----------
0x000253EF
```

Answer (score 2):

The return will be a 32 bit value where the most significant 8 bits is ch1, next 8 bits is ch2 and so on. The `<<` operator is a shift left operator, so if (in binary)

```
ch1 = 10101010
```

then (dots added for readability)

```
ch1 << 24 = 10101010.00000000.00000000.00000000
```

and so on. The `|` operator is an bitwise **OR** operator, so it just combines the variously shifted `ch` values.

Answer (score -1):

Break it down by steps:

1. It reads 4 8 bit bytes from the file pointed to by `hTTF` or returns EOF;
2. If it can read those 4 bytes, it creates a 4 byte value by bit or'ing the 4 bytes together after rotating each it turn.