# What does this statement mean?

Tags: java, android

Found it on [this website](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html).

```
holder.icon.setImageBitmap((position & 1) == 1 ? mIcon1 : mIcon2);
```

I'M asking for the "position & 1 ..."
I've seen this statement several times, but never knew what it means :/ Though I guess its handy to know :P

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are bitwise operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276706/what-are-bitwise-operators)

Answer (score 9):

`&` is the [*bitwise AND operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operator#AND).  Basically, `(position & 1)` is checking whether the least-significant bit of position is `1` or `0`, which is a way of checking whether `position` is odd or even.

For a full run-down of Java operators, see e.g. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) of (the value of) `position` and `1`.

So, if the least significant bit of `position` is `1` it will return `1`, otherwise it returns `0`.

Answer (score 1):

The single `&` sign is a bitwise AND operation.  You usually use them to apply a bit-mask.  In this case if `position`'s last (least significant) bit is 1 then `(position & 1) == 1` will be true since the `& 1` will zero everything except the last bit by "and-ing" each bit of 'position' with 1.