# What is a bitwise | operator

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

In lamens terms, what does a bitwise | operator do in Javascript and why is:

```
8 | 1 ; //9
```

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276706/what-are-bitwise-operators

Comment: [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Bitwise_operators)

Comment: Your asking for layman's terms on a programming forum?

Comment: question just has nothing to do with javascript in particular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*8 in binary = 1000

1 in binary = 0001*

if you take each binary digit and treat them as if statements (1 being true and 0 being false), you get this:

```
1 || 0 = 1
0 || 0 = 0
0 || 0 = 0
0 || 1 = 1
```

and the result is 1001, which is 9 in decimal

If it had been 8 & 1, it would go like this:

```
1 && 0 = 0
0 && 0 = 0
0 && 0 = 0
0 && 1 = 0
```

and the result would be 0

**Here's a quick example of how you might use these:**

You would use the OR operator if you wanted to combine masks -

Using an example of file permissions, you may have the following flags:

```
1st bit - execute (bin - 001, dec - 1)
2nd bit - write (bin - 010, dec - 2)
3rd bit - read (bin - 100, dec - 4)
```

If you wanted to create a mask for read and execute, you'd do something like `read value | execute value` which is `1 | 4` which would give you `5` (101 in bin)

Now you have a mask that you can check a file's permissions to see if it has both of these permissions, using the `&` operator:

*Example file 1 (has read, write, and execute)*

Its permission value is 7 (111 in bin): 111 & 101 = 101, so it does have those perms

*Example file 2 (has read and write)*

Its permission value is 6 (110 in bin): 110 & 101 = 100, so it only has the 100 (4 in dec) perms (read) of the two provided from the mask

Answer (score 2):

The `|` operator is a bitwise OR.

8 (base 10) is 1000 (base 2; binary).
1           is 0001

So, 8 | 1 (base 10) is equal to 1000 | 0001 binary, which is 1001 binary, which is 9 (base 10).

Answer (score 2):

All values on a computer are stored on the hardware in binary format.

```
1 = 0001
2 = 0010
3 = 0011
4 = 0100
etc.
```

`|` is the OR operater, which combines all bits from both values:

```
8 - 1000
1 = 0001
--------
9 = 1001
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your example, take the binary representations:

```
8 = 0b1000
1 = 0b0001
```

Then apply a logical OR to each bit (hence "bitwise"): For each bit, if either one, the other or both is/are 1 then the result is 1, else the result is 0.

```
8|1 = 0b1001
```

Which is 9.

Answer (score 1):

It takes the binary representation of two numbers, and finds the union ("or") between them.

Consider the two you gave:

```
binary(8) = 1000
binary(1) = 0001
```

So, if a bit is 1 in the first number (8) or the second number (1) or if it is 1 in both then it is carried down to the result.

So, `8 | 1 = 9`, because `1001` in binary is the result of the "or" operation and is 9 in decimal