# Bitwise operator "&"

Tags: javascript

I have trouble understanding "&" operator in javascript.
Why does this code

```
var wins = [7, 56, 448, 73, 146, 292, 273, 84];
var score=77;
for (i = 0; i < wins.length; i += 1) {
    alert((wins[i] & score)===wins[i])

        }
```

return true on win[3] , basicly why does

```
73&77==73
```

I just cant find the right answers.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/276706/497356

Comment: What else would you have expected?

Comment: `&` is "bitwise and" which means it's looking at the corresponding bits in the two values, and "and-ing" them (`1 & 1 = 1`, `1 & 0 = 0`, `0 & 1 = 0`, and `0 & 0 = 0`). If you translate 73 and 77 to binary, you get: `1001001 & 1001101` which has the result `1001001` (*bitwise* means you "and" each corresponding bit), that is, `73 & 77 === 73` is true.

Comment: Sounds like it's time you read up on [binary logical operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).