# How does number and number works in if statement?

Tags: javascript

What does `(number & number)` mean? I am trying to read someone's code written in JavaScript and came over with

```
if(misc & 0x800) {//...} //0x800 is 2048 when converted to decimal
```

Where `var misc = 16400; //or some other number which continuously changes`

So the statement is coming like `if(16400 & 2048)` -do something
When I `console.log()`ed those two numbers I got `0` .

How does if  statement works in case of number and number?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are bitwise operators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276706/what-are-bitwise-operators)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `&` means, that this is `bitwise AND`

The numbers are

`16400 (10) === 100000000010000 (2)`

`0x800 (16) === 100000000000 (2)`

Based on bitwise operation rules
The result will be:

```
100000000010000 
   100000000000
_______________
000000000000000
```

Such operations oftenly used for bit masks ([wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)))

Comment: But why to use those numbers? it could be simply written as If 0.

Comment: No it couldn't, because, for example, if misc will be 18448, the `18448 & 0x800` will be 2048, so it is trurhy. As you said `misc` changes continously, so your if will work depending on `misc` value.

Answer (score 1):

It is logical `and` operator.
It first converts both data to bit and the operat.

ex.

```
2 & 3
--> 010 & 011
--> 010
--> 2
```

Comment: If  you console.log() 011 & 010 you get 8. Why so?

Comment: Because 011 & 010 
--> 1001  & 1000 //  011 as a number will get converted to 1001 binary and 010 will get converted to 1000 binary
--> 1000 // This is binary representation
--> 8 // Number representation

Answer (score 1):

It is JavaScript's BitWise Operator (See more about it here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Bitwise '&' basically "Returns a one in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of both operands are ones." Read more in detail in the link above.