# what does the <<= operator do in javascript?

Tags: javascript, operators

I am working on a project for a javascript program as seen in the following...

```
var temp = 14;
var y 2;
temp <<= y;
document.write(temp)
```

....and I can't figure out how the <<= operator works of how this program works. Can someone please explain how it works? Thanks.

Comment: [It's the left-shift assignment operator.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators)

Comment: [What are bitwise operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276706/what-are-bitwise-operators)

Answer (score 2):

It is a bitwise left shift operator. For more details check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

`a << b`    Shifts a in binary representation b (< 32) bits to the left, shifting in zeroes from the right.

Comment: and oh by adding`=` you are just assigning it to some variable while also the shift taking place in same line of code