# Check if an array includes a value only one time in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, counting

i'm having two arrays of booleans:

```
arr1 = [true, false, false, true]
arr2 = [false, false, false ,true]
```

I want to make a function that is returning true only if arr1 and arr2 contains
true but only one true for each array. For example for the above arrays the function must return false. If the arrays are like this:

```
arr1 = [true, false, false, false]
arr2 = [false, false, false ,true]
```

the function will return true. Do tou know a quick way for achieving this without having to count the elements?

Comment: `without having to count the elements?` Regardless of the method, you'll have to iterate over each index/element until two trues are found (or the end is reached), there isn't really a way around that..?

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a quick method for it but i didnt find anything. Thanks :)

Comment: do you need to check two arrays at the same time? please add you attempt as well.

Comment: You might be better off [using bits and bitwise operations to act like flags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/276771/3233388)

Comment: And I am wondering if by _“wondering if there is a quick method for it”_ you mean you are actually worried about performance for some reason … or just that you want a “quick” copy&paste ready solution that frees you from making any efforts of your own. // http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 6):

You can check the value of first index and last index of the element to be same:

```js
function check(arr1, arr2){
  var firstIndexArr1 = arr1.indexOf(true);
  var lastIndexArr1 = arr1.lastIndexOf(true);
  var firstIndexArr2 = arr2.indexOf(true);
  var lastIndexArr2 = arr2.lastIndexOf(true);
  return (firstIndexArr1 !== -1 && firstIndexArr1 === lastIndexArr1) && 
  (firstIndexArr2 !== -1 && firstIndexArr2 === lastIndexArr2);
}
//return true
var arr1 = [true, false, false, false];
var arr2 = [false, false, false ,true];
console.log(check(arr1, arr2));

//return false
arr1 = [true, false, false, true];
arr2 = [false, true, false ,true];
console.log(check(arr1, arr2));

//return false if none of the array has true
arr1 = [false, false, false, false];
arr2 = [false, false, false ,false];
console.log(check(arr1, arr2));
```

Comment: @NitinBisht If there is something in the middle, first index and last index will be different.

Comment: @NitinBisht read the OP's question properly and investigate on `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`. You will find your answer.

Comment: @NinaScholz iterations? There is a `&&` condition which means that if first condition fails it will not check the second comparison. You say that a lot of iterations?

Answer (score 1):

you could search for the index of a value 2 times

```
function isUnique(myArray,value){
    let index = myArray.indexOf(value)
    if (index >= 0 && index+1 < myArray.length-1){
        return myArray.indexOf(value,index+1) == -1
    }
    return index >= 0 
}

// then
let result = isUnique(arr1,true) && isUnique(arr2,true)
```

Comment: You don't need the second part of the *if* condition. You can do everything after the *let* statement with `return index >= 0 && myArray.indexOf(value, index+1) == -1` or `return index >= 0 && myArray.lastIndexOf(value) == index`.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this function will do the trick.

```
 testFunc = () => {
   const arr1 = [true, false, false, false];
   const arr2 = [false, false, false ,true];

   return arr1.filter(val => val).length === 1 && arr2.filter(val => val).length === 1;
 };
```

Comment: OP's requirement is `without having to count the elements`. I think `filter` is somehow still loop thru all element and using `.length` should be a counting?

Comment: I assumed he does not want to write the code to count it , like running a loop and count. this solves the issue.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr2 = [true, false, false ,true];
var isOnlyOne = arr2.indexOf(true) != -1;
isOnlyOne = isOnlyOne ? arr2.indexOf(true)==arr2.lastIndexOf(true):isOnlyOne;
console.log(isOnlyOne );
```

The above logic can be used for your problem.