# How the vertical bar is used in following code

Tags: c++

I was decoding a c++ code and did not understand why is the vertical bar is used in the 6th line.

```
void build(int id, int l, int r) {
  if (l == r) {
    sum[id] = a[l];
    return;
  }
  int mid = (l + r) >> 1;
  build(id << 1, l, mid);
  build(id << 1 | 1, mid + 1, r); /*what operation does vertical
                                 bar perform with bitwise operator*/
  sum[id] = max(sum[id << 1], sum[id << 1 | 1]);
}
```

Comment: Before asking here, do some research. Maybe check the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are bitwise operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276706/what-are-bitwise-operators)

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
build(id<<1,l,mid);
build(id<<1|1,mid+1,r);
```

is equivalent to

```
build(2*id, l, mid);
build(2*id+1, mid+1, r);
```

The only difference is the first has been written by someone who thinks (wrongly) that it's more efficient than the second. A good programmer would prefer the second because it's easier to understand.

Comment: Most programmers would prefer the first, because it is easier to understand -- shifting in a 1 bit.  Mixing shift and add is more complex and harder to understand.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I didn't mix shift and add.

Answer (score 1):

The `|` is a bitwise or.  It takes two numbers as operands and does `OR` on each bit of the two numbers.

For example, consider the `OR`ing of the following tow bit patterns:
`00011010 | 10000111 = 10011111`