# Is there a more simple, less machine-level way of expressing or doing the same as (i & (1 << j))?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I found this bit of code (no pun intended) that solves a problem I needed to solve but I don't really understand what the (i & (1 << j)) part does. Is there a more "high level" way of writing it so I can understand it? Or a different way of doing the same thing that is less "pure"?

```
//this is not the actual code, just bits of it so you have an idea of how the variables are used

for (i = 0; i < vectorsize; i++) {
void findsubsets(unsigned int *value, int n, int i)
}

void findsubsets {
     for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (i & (1 << j)) {
            //print something
        }
    }
}
```

I would like an alternative to that statement, that does the same thing (or rather, solves the same problem) but is more "usual". I am of course only referring to the bitwise shift.

Comment: `i & (1 << j)` is actually quite readable IMO.  Why do you think it is "unusual"?

Comment: It's a bit test.  `i` is the value, `j` is the bit to test.

Comment: computers use binary and if you want to control them (efficiently) you need to know how to work with the binary digits, A.K.A bits using bitwise operators. [What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/141525/995714), [What are bitwise operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/276706/995714)

Comment: I'm kind of a newbie, so I haven't seen it yet.  But good to know it's not unusual.

Comment: Better to use `unsigned i` than `int i` and use `1u` than `1`.

Comment: Thanks! And why exactly is this expression important? What does it condition? I'm not sure I quite understand what it does yet. Be patient with me, I'm just getting started with coding :)

Answer (score 3):

That is very "usual".  It tests if the *j*th bit of `i` is set.  Another way is `if ((i >> j) & 1)`.

If you want it to be self documenting, write a nicely named helper function:

```
bool jth_bit(int i, int j) { return (i >> j) & 1; }
```

(Depending on which edition of C you use, you may want `_Bool` instead of `bool`)

Comment: Are you sure you got your i,j,1 in the right order or are you being cute?  nm - you are being cute.

Comment: "Depending on which edition of C"? Either you have both `_Bool` and `stdbool.h` with `typedef _Bool bool;`, or neither of them.

Comment: @R.. `typedef _Bool bool;` is not what's going on under the hood. The `bool` *macro* is defined as: `#define bool _Bool`.

Comment: Oops, embarrassing. Yes it's a macro not a typedef. But either way you either have both or neither.

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. Voigt has pointed out the expression `i & (1 << j)` simply checks if the `j`-th bit is set in the `i` variable. This is a pretty standard way of doing things in C.

To improve readability you can do this:

```
// Return value with n-th bit set to 1
int bit(int n) { return 1 << n; }

...

for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    if (i & bit(j))
    {
        //print something
    }
}
```

Another way is to "hide" the expression inside a function with a meaningful name:

```
bool is_bit_set_in(int var, int n) { return var & (1 << n); }

...

for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    if (is_bit_set_in(i, j))
    {
        //print something
    }
}
```