# What does int bit = (weight[i] & s) mean

Tags: c++

it is my first question, so I'm asking fot understanding. Below is function which converts a decimal number to binary. I do not understand what is happening here `int bit = (weight[i] & s)`:

```
void showbits(unsigned char s)
{
    unsigned char weight[8] = { 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128 };
    for (int = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        int bit = (weight[i] & s);
        if (bit != 0)
            cout << '1';
        else cout << '0';
    }
}
```

Comment: *I do not understand what is happening here* -- Assigning a value to an `int` variable.  So can you tell us in detail what is not understandable?

Comment: I missed the term, you are right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are bitwise operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276706/what-are-bitwise-operators)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, the `&` operator can have two meanings:

1. [address of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator) operator (when used as a unary operator)
2. [bitwise AND](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators) operator (when used as a binary operator)

Additionally, in C++ (but not in C), when used when declaring a variable, it can mean that the declared variable is a reference.

In the case you describe in your question, the `&` operator is the bitwise AND operator.

In order to understand what is going on, I will write all values of the `weight` array in binary representation:

```
00000001 (1)
00000010 (2)
00000100 (4)
00001000 (8)
00010000 (16)
00100000 (32)
01000000 (64)
10000000 (128)
```

By performing the bitwise AND operation with the function parameter `s` together with the values listed above, a certain bit will be extracted from the variable `s` in every loop iteration. In the first iteration of the loop, the least-significant (i.e. lowest) bit will be extracted and printed, in the second iteration of the loop the next bit will be extracted, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> What does int bit = (weight[i] & s) mean

```
T name = expression;
```

is syntax for variable declaration. The variable is copy initialised from the expression.

```
int bit = expression;
```

This declares the variable `bit` of type `int`.

```
array[index]
```

This is array subscripting operator. The result will be the value of the element of the array at the given index.

```
left & right
```

This is bitwise AND operation. Each bit of the result will be 1 if and only if the bit in the same position was 1 in both operands.

```
int bit = (weight[i] & s)
```

This combines all of the above. The parentheses can be used to change order of operations, but in this case they are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

This declaration

```
unsigned char weight[8] = { 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128 };
```

sets masks for bit-wise AND operation. You can rewrite it like

```
unsigned char weight[8] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80 };
```

So this bit-wise AND expression

```
weight[i] & s;
```

checks whether the corresponding bit in the object `s` is set to 1.

For example if s has the value `'\x65' then these operations with the masks`

```
'\x65' & 0x01
'\x65' & 0x04
'\x65' & 0x20
'\x65' & 0x40
```

will yield a result that unequal to 0.

Pay attention that there is a typo in your code

```
for (int = 7; i >= 0; i--)
```

here should be

```
for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void showbits( unsigned char c )
{
    unsigned char weight[8] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80 };

    for ( int i = 7; i >= 0; i-- )
    {
        std::cout << ( ( weight[i] & c ) ? '1' : '0'  );
    }

    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    char c = 'e';

    std::cout << "\'" << c << "\' - " << std::hex << static_cast<int>( c ) << '\n';

    showbits( c );
    return 0;
}
```

If the system supports ASCII coding then the output will be

```
'e' - 65
01100101
```