# check on element in a row in a data frame in pandas is NaN then replace it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

part of my data frame is as following:

```
personId    ActivityType    Time         Act_delay
1473237100  remote_work_4   57651.0      57651.0    
1473237100  home_2          59185.0      59185.0    
1473237100  remote_work_5   65849.0      65849.0    
1473237100  home_1          NaN          0.0
```

and I want to check if, in any row, the "ActivityType" column is equal to "home_1" and if "Time" column is NaN then replace "Act_delay" column to 10800.
I have the following code"

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
            if row['ActivityType'] == "home_1":
                if  row['Time'] == np.object:
                    df.loc[i,'Act_delay'] = 10800.0
```

but it does not work. the result is the same as before. what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looping in a dataframe is not recommended, instead we can leverage [bitwise `&`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276706/what-are-bitwise-operators) to combine the conditions (check variable `mask`) , then use [`df.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for boolean indexing and selecting the desired series to assign the values.

```
mask = df['ActivityType'].eq('home_1') & df['Time'].isna()

df.loc[mask, 'Act_delay'] = 10800
```

Output:

```
     personId   ActivityType     Time  Act_delay
0  1473237100  remote_work_4  57651.0    57651.0
1  1473237100         home_2  59185.0    59185.0
2  1473237100  remote_work_5  65849.0    65849.0
3  1473237100         home_1      NaN    10800.0
```

Comment: Love to see it @anky !

Comment: That's not a *little*. Thanks so much.