# Why do we use the bitwise or operator when we want to combine re.IGNORECASE and re.DOTALL?

Tags: python, regex, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

From my textbook (automate the boring stuff, Al Sweigart):
"If you want a regular expression that's case-insensitive *and* includes newlines to match the dot character, you would form your `re.compile()` call like this:

```
someRegexValue = re.compile('foo', re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
```

Unfortunately, the `re.compile()` function takes only a single value as its second argument. You can get around this limitation by combining the `re.IGNORECASE` and `re.DOTALL` variables using the pipe character (`|`), which in this context is known as the *bitwise or* operator.

This page is given as additional resource: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators/

I don't understand why we don't use the *bitwise and* operator instead. Referring to that page, if we regard x and y as some matching conditions and both must be applied at the same time, I would intuitively use the and operator...

Is there a reason why we can't do that?

Comment: A bit-wise and would always result in `0` for any combination of fields in the bitfield (except for the same).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are bitwise operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276706/what-are-bitwise-operators)

Comment: @RyszardCzech the post covers topics that are not familiar to me, so I am still having problems to understand the concept.

Answer (score 4):

The various `re.FLAGS` are part of a bit mask, with each flag being some value of 2 to occupy some bit position.  For example:

```
re.IGNORECASE =  2 = 00010
re.DOTALL     = 16 = 10000
```

Therefore, the expression `re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL` would generate the following bit mask:

```
10010
```

The flags parameter to many of the `re` library functions are expecting such a bitmask to decide which flags to apply.  If we were to bitwise `&` the above two operators, we would just get zero.  In fact, we would get zero for *any* bitwise `&` between two different flags, since no bits would ever be overlapping.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but it's still hard to understand. Maybe because I am not really familiar with bitwise operators, flags, bit masks and all that stuff you mentioned. Coming from if conditions in python and combining multiple conditions with and / or operators, I have to admit, this works differently with bitwise operators...

Comment: Maybe review the basics of bitwise `&` and `|`.

Comment: Ok, I have found this post, which also might be helpful. But I have to do some additional research on that topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276706/what-are-bitwise-operators?rq=1. Thanks.

Comment: @aurumpurum bit-level flagging is a really common approach in a lot of systems that need to track multiple on/off flags.  Not just regexes. You might for example see **required visible editable ....** tracked in a database column storing GUI field data.

Comment: "Ok, I have found this post, which also might be helpful"... but... that's the same one that you later said didn't answer your question (it does)?