# Compound &= |= ^= assignment operators when used with integers

Tags: c#

I am experimenting with the compound assignment operators and I understand how they work with boolean types but I do not understand how things work with integers or characters.

I know that this is not useful, I am just experimenting.
So I have this integer that has the value of 10 and whenever I do the following, it outputs 12 but I do not know why.
Please help me.

```
int oppo = 10;
Console.WriteLine(oppo^=6);
```

Comment: Is your question about integer vs character vs boolean, or is it about compound vs simple operator, e.g. `Console.WriteLine(oppo^=6);` vs `oppo^=6; Console.WriteLine(oppo);` vs `Console.WriteLine(oppo ^ 6);`  Because an explanation about compound assignment will tell you nothing about the different data types, and vice versa, they are two totally different questions.

Comment: No, I am trying to understand when doing this Console.WriteLine(oppo^=6);  why does it output 12.

Comment: @EricMovsessian `b1010` (`10`) XOR `b0110` (`6`) results in `b1100`, which is `12`. What exactly is the question?

Comment: That's easily explained by looking at XOR: `int x = 10 ^ 6; Console.WriteLine(x);`  Has nothing to do with a compound assignment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/276724/103167

Comment: Okay thanks, sorry about the question, did not think deeply enough.