# C programming Bitwise operator &= struggling to understand what its doing

Tags: c, pic

I am trying to work out how this part of this code is working. REF state &= 0X07;

```
static uint8_t state = 0;
    /*  values for half step             0001, 0011, 0010, 0110, 0100, 1100, 1000, 1001*/
    static const uint8_t HalfSteps[8] = {0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x06, 0x04, 0x0C, 0x08, 0x09};
    uint8_t delay;

    do
    {
        if (Count > 0)
        {
            PORTC = HalfSteps[state];   /* drive stepper to select state */
            state++;                    /* step one state clockwise */
            state &= 0x07;              /* keep state within HalfStep table */
            Count--;
```

The part after the state++ will increase from start of 0 and I know its resetting to 0 after goes above 7.

But not sure how this is achieved I have read that it basically means.

state = state + 7 but that does not look right.

Any easy explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: It means `state = state & 7;`.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276706/what-are-bitwise-operators

Comment: Are you familiar with bitwise operators in C?  The `&` operator is bitwise-AND.  Each bit in the result is a 1 if and only if it is a 1 in both operands.  The `&=` operator is just a bitwise assignment operator:  `x &= y;` is equivalent to `x = x & y;`.

Comment: Your loop is just using the last 3 bits of `state` as a 3-bit counter.  It counts from 0 to 7, then goes back to 0 (since 8 & 7 is 0).

Comment: Thanks for the assistance I am new to bitwise operators but think I can see Toms 2nd comment answers the question. also Davids answer is correct I Like to understand code before I use it and this had me stumped how it worked.

Comment: Hi Phuclv Yes that did help in the past I had used the if statement shown in answer 2 which worked for me. Seeing the &= throw me off so thanks for this.  'if(step > 7) step = 0;'

Comment: Hi Nick Yes that was helpful sorry I did not reply earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following three lines are all equivalent:

```
state &= 0x07;
state = state & 7;
state = state % 8;
```

The effect is to ensure that the state is always less than 8, and also that the state that comes after 7 is 0, not 8.

Comment: Thank you David I need to get my head around the use of some of the basic mathematics  as I did not learn any of this at school and having retired and wanting to program in C there is so much to take in. Modulo is something new to me.