# Resources to learn bitwise programming?

Tags: c++, language-agnostic

I am a c++ programmer and occasionally I'll come across some code that is using bitwise operators to manipulate things at the bit level, but I have no real understanding of those concepts. So I would like a resource to help me learn it so well that it becomes second nature. Does anyone know of good resources for this? A google search did not provide me much useful information. Maybe I'm not sure what to look for. Thanks!

Comment: In high level languages, I've always missed the rotate-through-carry instructions. If I ever design a language, it'll have that.

Comment: What kind of apps do you need that in? I'm guessing coms.

Comment: Well, by having it, it's easier to do multibyte shifts. Whatever you need it for. Stuff I drop down into assembly to do. Maybe instead of the shift and rotate through carry, I could do something higher level, like allow bitwise on arrays of integers.

Comment: Come to think of it, why the heck can't I do a << or a >> on an array and have the bits move through the bytes? Why can't I do a bitwise or on two equal-sized arrays of ints in one operation?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I absolutely love Henry Warren's [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/) book.  The website for it offers Chapter 2 ("Basics") as a free sample which, despite the name, offers some fairly sophisticated bit manipulation tricks.  It might not be the best place to start, but it's fantastic once you start to get comfortable with bit arithmetic.

Comment: +1 for Hacker's Delight - it's an excellent book which I'm constantly referring back to for fast ways to perform all sorts of algorithms

Comment: Also +1 for this great book. Though not all of the bit-twiddling is a win these days, it's still fascinating stuff.

Comment: Although there are lots of good web links listed, this book strikes me as just what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: man aren't there any animated videos

Comment: @JimDaniel did the book Hacker's Delight help you?? I have problems in bit manipulation and I am looking for a good book.

Comment: @FatemehKarimi what helped you?

Answer (score 8):

You'll have to know the background of the binary system. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system has a great overview. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation for bitwise operations.

Answer (score 5):

**Here are a few:**

- [Dev Articles -> Bitwise Operators](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/Bitwise-Operators/)
- [GameDev.net -> Bitwise Operators](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1563.asp)
- [Wikipedia -> Bitwise Operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)
- [Code Project -> Bitwise Operations](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/bitbashing.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Well, I guess every c/c++ book explains bitwise operators. 
There are also a lot of tutorials online.If I were you, I would improve my google skills. Delicious also has a good search functionality. Here are some of the links I have found:

http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1563.asp

http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html

http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

http://resnet.uoregon.edu/~gurney_j/jmpc/bitwise.html

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html

http://www.catonmat.net/blog/low-level-bit-hacks-you-absolutely-must-know/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/bitbashing.aspx

http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4ab.html

http://www.cs.utk.edu/~vose/c-stuff/bithacks.html

http://www.somacon.com/p125.php

http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/expressions/bitops.html

http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~stbird/Tutorials/BitwiseOps.html

http://www.custard.org/~andrew/programming/bitwise/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/Bitwise_Operation.aspx

http://bits.stephan-brumme.com/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation

http://www.hackersdelight.org/HDcode.htm

http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/BitMath

http://irc.essex.ac.uk/www.iota-six.co.uk/c/e4_bitwise_operators_and_or_xor.asp

Answer (score 2):

I imagine there are other possibly better resources, but I remembered that there was an article on this I read a few years ago on GameDev.Net.

[BitWise Operations in C](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1563.asp)

Comment: I just linked to that same one, It was in my Google Chrome bookmarks. It was a really good tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the responses above on that GameDev.net article. That was a good one for me in the past.

This article on Denormalization with Bitmasks (http://maggienelson.com/2009/02/denormalization-with-bitmasks/) was useful to me as well and includes database-specific examples, in case those are of use.