# Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(IntPtr ptr, T structure) throws [System.ArgumentException]: The structure must not be a value class

Tags: c#

I think there might be a bug in the C# method

```
Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(IntPtr ptr, T structure)
```

I wrongly assumed `T structure` means you can pass in your structure you want to fill but when I do this as in the example below an exception is thrown:

> [System.ArgumentException: The structure must not be a value class.
>   Parameter name: structure]

To give you a simple example:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyStruct s = new MyStruct();

        var buffer = new Byte[]{1,2,3};
        var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        Marshal.PtrToStructure<MyStruct>(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), s);
        handle.Free();
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    struct MyStruct
    {
        public Byte a;
        public Byte b;
        public Byte c;
    }
}
```

Am I reading the method decleration wrong?  Or is there a bug?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_PtrToStructure__1_System_IntPtr___0_ https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0372911d-c200-47f0-91ac-a35428751e6b/what-is-a-quotformatted-classquot?forum=clr

Comment: If you think about it, this can't work for structs anyway, since arguments are passed by value. If the method filled out the copy of `s` you passed it, that wouldn't affect `s` for you.

Comment: I'm not going to dupe-hammer it, but there are other questions here about this. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079868/marshal-ptrtostructure-throwing-system-argumentexception-error

Comment: Not a bug, this is a documented exception.  But sure, it was a design mistake.  That's why the method overload has the [Obsolete] attribute.  It can only work when T is a class, that makes the name of the method rather painful.  No biggie, just omit the second argument and use the return value.  You do want to dig a bit why you did not get the obsoletion diagnostic.

Comment: I updated the question because I didn't relize the <T> was missing from the method.  The full method is Marshal.PtrToStructure<T>(IntPtr ptr, T structure)

Comment: @Blorgbeard no this is not the same he is using the deprecated version wihtout the type specifier look at the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_PtrToStructure__1_System_IntPtr___0_)

Comment: It's the same issue though. You can't pass a struct to a method "to be filled out". You need to use the other overload, which returns the result: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_PtrToStructure__1_System_IntPtr_

Comment: And quoting from the link in your comment: "You cannot use this method overload with value types." - so it's working as documented.

Comment: It's definitely confusing design though, calling the parameter `structure` and then forbidding `struct` with a runtime exception that says "value class" instead of "value type".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Blorgbeard.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter name `structure` is misleading here. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure?view=netcore-3.1#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_PtrToStructure__1_System_IntPtr___0_) calls out twice that it must be a class.

> The type of structure. This must be a formatted class.

> You cannot use this method overload with value types.

However, it also self-contradicts itself when it says

> Structure layout is not sequential or explicit.

Looking at the [actual source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/Marshal.cs#L570), you don't find a `where T : class` constraint either which I guess given the docs should be present.

Answer (score 0):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
class MyStruct
{
    public Byte a;
    public Byte b;
    public Byte c;
}
```

Had this problem myself and found that changing the structure to a class (ref type) over comes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting your struct to a class (or record, I presume), there is a new overload in 4.5.1 and newer (and .NET core), which did work for me using a struct.

```
var msgReceived = new FixedLengthStruct();
unsafe
{
  fixed(byte* buffer = memoryAccessor.Bytes)
  {
    msgReceived = Marshal.PtrToStructure<FixedLengthStruct>((IntPtr)buffer);
  }
}
// Process msgReceived
```

My struct here used LayoutKind.Explicit.