# find a point which perpendicular to given line

Tags: math, equation, cartesian

I want to find a point z(x3,y3) which perpendicular to given line. In my example I am given 2 coordinates A(x1 , y1) and B(x2 , y2). I want to find the point z which is perpendicular(AZ) to AB line and distance (h) from point B. ABZ angle is 90.
here is my c++ code.

`double AB_slope = m; // know it`

//find z point which perpendicular to AB line

`double AZ_slope = - 1/m;`

`double x3 = x2 + prescribed_distance * dx;`

`double y3 = y2 + prescribed_distance * dy;`

But I don't know to find dx , dy and prescribed_distance. please help me.

Comment: Point cannot be perpendicular to a line.

Comment: This is a math question, ask it on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: does the problem condition include `h` value or you want just to find any point of the line that goes through `A` and orthogonal to `AB`?

Comment: @devan, If you want help, you need to participate, and explain more what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me rephrase your question to be what I think it is, then answer it.

You're given points `A = (x1, y1)` and `B = (x2, y2)`.  You want to find a point `Z = (x3, y3)` such that `AZ` is perpendicular to `AB`, and `BZ` has length `h`.

The vector from `A` to `B` is `v = (x2 - x1, y2 - y1)`.  An easy to calculate perpendicular vector to that one is `w = (y2 - y1, x1 - x2)`.  The line crossing through `A` which is perpendicular to `AB` is represented by `F(s) = A + s*w = (x1 + s*(y2 - y1), y1 + s*(x1 - x2))` as `s` ranges over the real numbers.  So we need to pick a value `s` such that `F(s)` is `h` away from `B`.

From the Pythagorean theorem, the square of the length from `F(s)` to `B` is always going to be the square of the distance from `F(s)` to `A`, plus the square of the distance from `A` to `B`.  From which we get the messy expression that we want:

```
h**2 = s**2 * ((y2 - y1)**2 + (x1-x2)**2) + ((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2))
     = s**2 * ((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)) + ((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2))
     = (s**2 + 1) * ((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2))

(s**2 + 1) = h**2 / ((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2))

s**2  = h**2 / ((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)) - 1

s = sqrt(h**2 / ((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 - y2)**2)) - 1)
```

Now plug that expression for `s` back into `F(s) = (x1 + s*(y2 - y1), y1 + s*(x1 - x2))` and you have your point `Z`.  And the other possible answer is the same distance on the other side.

Comment: There are an infinite amount of points that are h away from B (assuming a realistic h > AB) and that a line can be drawn perpendicular to AB through A.  In fact the set of all those points describes a circle centered around A.

Comment: @Lance Roberts In 3 dimensions the set of such points will describe a circle.  In 4 dimensions it will form a sphere.  But the code given was for 2 dimensions, and then you'll get 2 points.  The technique I gave finds those points.

Comment: Ok, in 2D sure, +1.  (though we may never know what the OP really wants).

Comment: @btilly Please could you clarify the meaning of `**` in this answer? e.g. `h**2`

Comment: @Styne666 It means exponentiation.  In many C-derived programming languages (eg C, C++, Java, Perl, Ruby, ...) ^ means xor, so ** got used instead for exponentiation.

Comment: @btilly Ah, but C++ [doesn't seem to have `**`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3775274/594137). That would be why I've never seen it! Thank you.

Comment: @Styne666 you're right.  I just assumed that the math operators in Perl were lifted from C along with the precedence table, but I was wrong.  However Java, Perl and Ruby all use ** for exponents.