# & vs * and | vs +

Tags: numpy

When doing *boolean* array comparison, is there any advantage / convention to using `&` in place of `*` or `|` in place of `+`?  Are these always equivalent?

(if these are in the documentation, a link would probably be an acceptable answer, but my naive search for 'numpy ampersand' and 'numpy elementwise boolean comparison' didn't yield anything relevant)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In numpy `&` and `|` are equivalent to [`np.bitwise_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html) and [`np.bitwise_or`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html). You can also use `^` for [`np.bitwise_xor`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_xor.html). This is all documented in the [Arithmetic and comparison operations](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arithmetic-and-comparison-operations) section of the ndarray docs. There are also ufuncs for [`np.logical_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html), [`np.logical_or`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html) and [`np.logical_xor`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_xor.html).

If your arrays are all of dtype `bool` there shouldn't be any difference. I personally lean towards `&` and `|`, even though if you are not strict about the `bool` dtype it can get you in troubles like this:

```
In [30]: np.array(2) & np.array(1)
Out[30]: 0
```

Answer (score 6):

In case someone wondered: the operations have the same speed and it therefore does not matter which one you choose.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.random.randn(1000)>0

In [3]: b = np.random.randn(1000)>0

In [4]: %timeit a*b
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.89 us per loop

In [5]: %timeit a&b
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.87 us per loop

In [6]: %timeit a+b
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.69 us per loop

In [7]: %timeit a|b
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.62 us per loop
```

As far as I am concerned, I use `&` and `|` to make explicit that I'm interested in a boolean operation (in case the reader forgot the dtype of the arrays in question).