# 2D list redefinition with condition inside brackets: how do I impose complex conditions?

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements, mapping

So I have a 2D matrix, in the code called `wave[2]` (it's the place-2 element of the three-dimensional array `wave`), which I want to map into a matrix of equal dimensions but with the condition that if the element I am mapping is between -0.001 and 0.001 I will map it into a 0, otherwise I will map into a np.nan value. This is what I wrote to do so:

```
zeros=np.array(n,n)
zeros[wave[2] < 0.01 and wave[2] > -0.01] = 0
zeros[wave[2] > 0.01 or wave[2] < -0.01] = np.nan
```

But I guess passing two conditions inside the brackets is not legal, because I get this error message: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. I'm not able to fix it.

Comment: maybe - `np.logical_and(wave[2] < 0.01, wave[2] > -0.01)` or `wave[2] < 0.01 & wave[2] > -0.01`

Comment: Related (dupe?): [Logical operators for Boolean indexing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas), and  [& vs * and | vs +](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679595/vs-and-vs)