# how to check if my strings are not empty in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if Region != " " & State != " " & Sku != " ":
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

for single string I got it, but for multiple it shows above error

Thanks in advance

Comment: the issue isnt with the individual conditions, but with how you're joining them together. python uses `and` for logical AND. Also, parenthesis makes conditions clear.

Comment: FWIW, these strings are not empty. They contain a single whitespace. An empty string is `''` or `""`.

Comment: In any case check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556206/what-does-mean-in-python that will help you understand how the operator is used

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In python, you can evaluate strings as a boolean. It returns True if its no empty and it returns True if its empty. So you have to code this:

`if not Region and not State and not Sku:`

Comment: OP apparently needs to check for a single whitespace, not the empty string

Comment: Or it is just mistake. Hard to say, better to be specific.

Answer (score 3):

As DeepSpace points out, your strings are not empty. Consider:

`if Region.strip() != "" and State.strip() != "" and Sku.strip() != "":`

Also, you may want to use lower case variable names, as it is considered good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Use `and` instead of `&`.

```
  if Region != " " and State != " " and Sku != " ":
```

Comment: welcome ! @Ashok