# What does &\ mean in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I came across the code below,

```
period=volume[((volume['Id']==report.at[report.index[report_id],'id']) & \
                                       (volume['Time']>=start_time) & \
                                      (volume['Time']<=test_time))]
```

I read a post on [operator &](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8556206/11901732) but what does it mean by `&\` and what is this snippet of code doing?

Comment: It means the author doesn't know that inside parentheses, you don't need ``\`` to tell Python the logical line isn't finished but continues on the next physical line.

Comment: The backslash at the end of a line escapes the linebreak and effectively means: continue in the next line. In the given case it is not even necessary since there are brackets open.

Comment: `&\ ` are two characters that just happened to be together. `&` is the bitwise _and_ operator.`\ ` is a line continuation character.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslash doesn't create another operator with the `&`, it is just used to allow one long statement to continue onto the next line for readability. So the code is equivalent to

```py
period=volume[((volume['Id']==report.at[report.index[report_id],'id']) & (volume['Time']>=start_time) & (volume['Time']<=test_time))]
```